# ODI || Create Multiple Rows From Single Comma Separated Row

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I have a comma separated list of values for 2 columns and a unique key for single row. I want to create a single row for each comma separated row with key repeating for each value.

For Example,
I have

```
Unique_Id ||  Date                 || Price
abc       || 2013/01/10,2013/01/11 || 12,13
```

What I want is

```
abc || 2013/01/10 || 12
abc || 2013/01/11 || 13
```

The comma separated values can be upto n.

I am using ODI 11g (Oracle Data Integrator).
How can I do this?

Comment: What did you do to solve your problem self? Do you have a code fragment or at least any idea?

Comment: I resolved this scenario using an ODI procedure

Comment: here is a nice solution :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14328621/oracle-10g-splitting-string-into-multiple-rows

Comment: i have used the same RegExpr approach in procedure, but using connect by was creating excption ODI