# oracle -- Split multiple comma separated values in oracle table to multiple rows

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, split

I Have a problem with oracle split query.

While splitting comma separated data into multiple rows using connect by and regular expression in oracle query I am getting more **duplicate rows**. for example actually my table having 150 rows in that one two rows having comma separated strings so overall i have to get only 155 rows but i am getting 2000 rows. If i use distinct its working fine but i dont want duplicate rows in query result.

I tried the following query however it's generating duplicate rows in query result:

```
WITH CTE AS (SELECT 'a,b,c,d,e' temp,1 slno  FROM DUAL
              UNION 
              SELECT 'f,g',2 from dual
              UNION 
               SELECT 'h',3 FROM DUAL)

SELECT TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR( TEMP, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL)) ,SLNO FROM CTE 
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH(REGEXP_REPLACE(temp, '[^,]+')) + 1
```

**EDIT**

The above select query is only able to split a **single comma delimited string**, however, it produces duplicate rows when executed on a table with **multiple rows**. How to restrict the duplicate rows?

Comment: This question is not a duplicate of the other question marked as duplicate. The other question is splitting a single row, and this question is about multiple rows.

Comment: The accepted answer uses the condition `DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE IS NOT NULL` which is inappropriate. It just prevents the cyclic loop, however a straight forward question would come up as **How and when dbms_random.VALUE can be null?** Logically, it will never be NULL.

More appropriate solution is to use `sys.odciNumberList` and prevent the cyclic loop. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finally I came up with this answer

```
WITH CTE AS (SELECT 'a,b,c,d,e' temp, 1 slno FROM DUAL
              UNION
              SELECT 'f,g' temp, 2 slno FROM DUAL
              UNION
              SELECT 'h' temp, 3 slno FROM DUAL)
SELECT TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR(temp, '[^,]+', 1, level)), slno
FROM CTE
CONNECT BY level <= REGEXP_COUNT(temp, '[^,]+')
    AND PRIOR slno = slno
    AND PRIOR DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Regarding your comment [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14331055/696632), why does this work and does not produce dupliate lines? Ther random seems to prevent a cyclic loop.

Comment: Logically, `PRIOR DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE IS NOT NULL` makes no sense. How and when `dbms_random.VALUE` can be null? The better way is using `sys.odciNumberList`. See few demos here https://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2015/03/04/split-comma-delimited-strings-in-a-table-using-oracle-sql/

Answer (score 5):

Try like this,

```
WITH CTE AS (SELECT 'a,b,c,d,e' temp,1 slno  FROM DUAL
              UNION 
              SELECT 'f,g',2 from dual
              UNION 
              SELECT 'h',3 FROM DUAL)
     SELECT regexp_substr (temp, '[^,]+', 1, rn)temp, slno
     FROM   cte
     CROSS JOIN 
     (
          SELECT ROWNUM rn
          FROM  (SELECT MAX (LENGTH (regexp_replace (temp, '[^,]+'))) + 1 max_l
                 from cte
                 )
          connect by level <= max_l
         )
     WHERE regexp_substr (temp, '[^,]+', 1, rn) IS NOT NULL
     order by temp;
```

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer uses the condition `DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE IS NOT NULL` which is inappropriate. It just prevents the cyclic loop, however a straight forward question would come up as **How and when `dbms_random.VALUE` can be null?** Logically, it will never be **NULL**.

More appropriate solution is to use **sys.odciNumberList** and prevent the cyclic loop.

For example,

**Set up**

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE t (
  2    ID          NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
  3    text        VARCHAR2(100)
  4  );

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> INSERT INTO t (text) VALUES ('word1, word2, word3');

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO t (text) VALUES ('word4, word5, word6');

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO t (text) VALUES ('word7, word8, word9');

1 row created.

SQL> COMMIT;

Commit complete.

SQL>
SQL> SELECT * FROM t;

        ID TEXT
---------- ----------------------------------------------
         1 word1, word2, word3
         2 word4, word5, word6
         3 word7, word8, word9

SQL>
```

**Required query:**

```
SQL> SELECT t.id,
  2         trim(regexp_substr(t.text, '[^,]+', 1, lines.column_value)) text
  3  FROM t,
  4    TABLE (CAST (MULTISET
  5    (SELECT LEVEL FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= regexp_count(t.text, ',')+1)
  6                 AS sys.odciNumberList
  7                )
  8          ) lines
  9  ORDER BY id
 10  /

        ID TEXT
---------- --------------------------------------------------
         1 word1
         1 word2
         1 word3
         2 word4
         2 word5
         2 word6
         3 word7
         3 word8
         3 word9

9 rows selected.
```

**An alternate solution using `XMLTABLE`:**

```
SQL> SELECT id,
  2         trim(COLUMN_VALUE) text
  3  FROM t,
  4    xmltable(('"'
  5    || REPLACE(text, ',', '","')
  6    || '"'))
  7  /

        ID TEXT
---------- ------------------------
         1 word1
         1 word2
         1 word3
         2 word4
         2 word5
         2 word6
         3 word7
         3 word8
         3 word9

9 rows selected.

SQL>
```

There are many ways to achieve the task, like a **MODEL** clause. For more examples see [**Split comma delimited strings in a table**](http://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2015/03/04/split-comma-delimited-strings-in-a-table-using-oracle-sql/)

Comment: can this be extended to multiple columns ..?  I have a table with 3 columns in which 2 of them are , separated , I need to convert them to multiple rows .   COL1 = a,b,c    COL2 = x,y,z and I need 9 rows   a-x , a-y , a-z, b-x, b-y,b-z , x-z,c-y,c-z    -- Is this something possible ?

Comment: @NuthanKumar Just concatenate the two columns in the regular expression of select.

Comment: I just came across this answer. I don't understand your objection to using `prior dbms_random.value() is not null`. (Note that the whole point of this is the `PRIOR` operator.) Of course that value is never NULL; the point of this condition is not to provide a way to break out of the recursion (other conditions play that role), but to add a non-repeating pseudo-column to the ones Oracle uses to find cycles in the hierarchical query. These days `PRIOR sys_guid() is not null` is seen more often, playing exactly the same role.

Comment: @mathguy Because logically it is never NULL, sys.odciNumberList makes more sense.

Answer (score 2):

without using **connect by**:

```
WITH CTE AS (SELECT 'a,b,c,d,e' temp,1 slno  FROM DUAL
      UNION 
      SELECT 'f,g',2 from dual
      UNION 
       SELECT 'h',3 FROM DUAL
)
,x as (
  select
  ','||temp||',' temp
  ,slno
  from CTE
)
,iter as (SELECT rownum AS pos
    FROM all_objects
)
select
SUBSTR(x.temp
  ,INSTR(x.temp, ',', 1, iter.pos) + 1
  ,INSTR(x.temp, ',', 1, iter.pos + 1)-INSTR(x.temp, ',', 1, iter.pos)-1
) temp
,x.slno
from x, iter
where iter.pos < = (LENGTH(x.temp) - LENGTH(REPLACE(x.temp, ','))) - 1;
```

Comment: +1 much more simple and understandable - join each comma-separated row with a dummy table big enough to contain more rows than values in each of your comma-separated lists (so you get cartesian result), and use either substr as above or regexp_substr. great.

Answer (score 0):

Can use the below query to convert comma separated values in rows

```
 SELECT trim(x.column_value.extract('e/text()')) COLUMNS
 from t t, table (xmlsequence(xmltype('<e><e>' || replace(valuestring,':','</e><e>')||  
 '</e></e>').extract('e/e'))) x   );
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding an unique clause does the trick:

```
    WITH cte AS (
        SELECT 'a,b,c,d,e' temp, 1 slno FROM DUAL UNION 
        SELECT 'f,g',2 FROM DUAL UNION SELECT 'h',3 FROM DUAL
    ) SELECT UNIQUE(slno),REGEXP_SUBSTR(temp,'[^,]+', 1, LEVEL)temp FROM cte
    CONNECT BY LEVEL<=REGEXP_COUNT(temp, '[^,]+') ORDER BY slno;
```