# How to split string using a matching string in Oracle using regexp?

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

Currently I've this, but it is returning `null`.

```
select  regexp_substr(  'abcx1bcdx2mno',  '[^x[[:digit:]]]+', 1,1 ) from dual;
select  regexp_substr(  'abcx1bcdx2mno',  '[^x[[:digit:]]]+', 1,1 ) from dual;
```

I want to have it such a way, that the first query returns `abc`, and second one returns `bcd`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately we cannot negate a group of characters(search string). As a workaround we could replace our search string with a single character, space for example, and then negate that one character:

Here is a simple example:

```
with t1(col) aS(
  select 'abcx1bcdx2mno' from dual
)
select regexp_substr( regexp_replace(col, 'x[[:digit:]]', ' '), '[^ ]+'
                     , 1, level) as res
  from t1
connect by level <= regexp_count( regexp_replace(col, 'x[[:digit:]]', ' ')
                                 , '[^ ]+')
```

**Note**: `regexp_count()` regular expression function introduced in oracle 11g version.

Result:

```
RES         
-------------
abc           
bcd           
mno
```

Comment: @user1732386 Previous approach might produce wrong result due to inability negate a group of characters. Answer has been updated.

Comment: Thanks. If I've space in the string, then it is not splitting correctly. For example, if I've 'abcx1bcdx2 s1 33 mno', then I would like to see splits as abc, bcd,  s1 33 mno. But it is splitting with space too. Also, what if there are newline characters.

Comment: @user1732386 If space is part of a string you could introduce a different character that is not part of a string you are trying to split, period or comma for instance. You could use `n` flag to allow `.`(period) to match newline or you could do multi-line  search using `m` flag.

Comment: This one does not work if you have more than one line in `t1`.

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20399166/696632) is a better answer.