# Separate the values from the data column

Tags: database, plsql

I have a column with data like

```
I~A~G~S
```

How could i separate them using select query.

Output :
**Updated**

```
  Rows       Column(Data)
  First      I
  Second     A
  Third      G
  Fourth     S
```

Comment: is this what you are expecting?
select replace('I~A~G~S','~',' ') as x from dual;

you can use replace function in oracle. you replace the ~ with with space.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18770581/oracle-split-multiple-comma-separated-values-in-oracle-table-to-multiple-rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are using oracle database then it should be as follows:

```
select replace('I~A~G~S','~',' ') as x from dual;

select replace(<fieldname>,'~',' ') from <tablename>
```

as for the question of splitting the string in different rows please check the below query.

```
SELECT trim(regexp_substr(replace('I~A~G~S','~',','), '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL)) str_2_tab
  FROM dual
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= regexp_count(replace('I~A~G~S','~',','), ',')+1;
```

Comment: you are welcome.
if the answer has answered all you questions, please mark as answered.
thnxs

Comment: can we get I~A~G~S into different- different variables like income = I, Age=A, Gender=G and State=S;

Answer (score 2):

```
declare @s varchar(10)
set @s='I~A~G~S'

select replace(@s,'~',' ')
```

for `updated question`

```
create table #vij11 (s varchar(100))

insert into #vij11(s) values ('I~A~G~S')
SELECT   
     Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS String  
 FROM  (SELECT [s],  
         CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE([s], '~', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS String  
     FROM  #vij11) AS A CROSS APPLY String.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a);
```

<kbd>[fiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f6c57/1)</kbd>

Comment: Could i get the same as values in different-2 row. like I in first row then A in 2nd row.

Comment: what you mean ? like I A G S *2

Comment: FIRST ROW I, SECOND ROW A , THIRD ROW G , FOURTH ROW S

Comment: @Java_Alert i have updated the answer above for splitting the string in different rows. please check

Comment: can we get I~A~G~S into different- different variables like income = I, Age=A, Gender=G and State=S;