# Insert splitted values from comma separated list

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I want to insert the values ​​in a column from one table to another but the values ​​of the first table are stored in a single string, separated by commas.
I have to insert all values ​​automatically without specifying the id, hence  creating the following.

```
TABLE_1

ID_TRA | COND
------------
100    | 1,2,4
101    | 4
102    | 1, 16  <--- TRIM SPACE

TABLE_2
ID | ID_TRA | COND_ID
---------------------
1  | 100    | 1
2  | 100    | 2
3  | 100    | 4
4  | 101    | 4
5  | 102    | 1
6  | 102    | 16
```

**Note**

The id needs to be auto incremented as it's being inserted

Comment: Never, ever store data as comma separated values. It will only cause you lots of trouble.

Comment: The values ​​were so when they sent me this functionality

Comment: And you have to deal with it... Too bad.

Comment: @jarlh - It happens everywhere and all the time though. Very often it's legacy - from times before RMDB's even existed. Large organization, especially, refuse to spend the time and money to fix their data model.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Splitting comma separated values in Oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28271744/splitting-comma-separated-values-in-oracle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an insert-select this way:

```
insert into table_2(ID, ID_TRA, COND_ID)
SELECT ROWNUM, ID_TRA, COND_ID
FROM (
        SELECT ID_TRA,
               trim (' ' from REGEXP_SUBSTR( COND, '([^,]*)(,|$)', 1, LEVEL, NULL, 1 ) ) AS COND_ID
        FROM   table_1 t
        CONNECT BY
               ID_TRA = PRIOR ID_TRA
        AND    PRIOR SYS_GUID() IS NOT NULL
        AND    LEVEL < REGEXP_COUNT( COND, '([^,]*)(,|$)' )
        ORDER BY 1, 2
        )
```

The ordering is important to decide how to assing the `ID` in your table; you can edit it by modifying the `ORDER BY`.
The way to split the strings is taken from [SO documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20170914140540/https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/oracle/1968/splitting-delimited-strings#t=201709141405407224393).

If you need to add new rows to the `table_2`, not populating it from scratch, you should better use a sequence; the solution with `rownum` only works if the target table is empty.

Comment: Thanks for all friend.

Comment: If i put sequence on select stament not work?

insert into table_2(ID, ID_TRA, COND_ID)
SELECT MY_SQ.nextval, ID_TRA, COND_ID
FROM (
        SELECT ID_TRA,
               trim (' ' from REGEXP_SUBSTR( COND, '([^,]*)(,|$)', 1, LEVEL, NULL, 1 ) ) AS COND_ID
        FROM   table_1 t
        CONNECT BY
               ID_TRA = PRIOR ID_TRA
        AND    PRIOR SYS_GUID() IS NOT NULL
        AND    LEVEL < REGEXP_COUNT( COND, '([^,]*)(,|$)' )
        ORDER BY 1, 2
        )

Comment: If you want a sequence, simply use your_sequence.nextVal instead of ROWNUM in the external query

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
insert into table_2(ID, ID_TRA, cond)
select rownum,id_tra,trim(regexp_substr(t.cond, '[^,]+', 1, levels.column_value))  as prjcd from table_1 t,
table(cast(multiset(select level from dual connect by  level <= length (regexp_replace(t.cond, '[^,]+'))  + 1) as sys.OdciNumberList)) levels;
```