# How to use comma separated values from listagg in inner query?

Tags: sql, oracle, listagg, inner-query

Consider the query

```
select listagg(''''||Name||'''', ',') within group (order by Name) from STUDENTS;
```

This gives me output as

```
'Jon','Rob','Bran'
```

How do I use this in inner query consider the following example:

```
with lst as(
select listagg(''''||Name||'''', ',') within group (order by Name) as name_list from STUDENTS)
select * from result where Name in (select name_list from lst)
```

Expected result :

```
-----------------
| Name  | Score |
-----------------
| Jon   | 80    |
-----------------
| Rob   | 60    |
-----------------
| Bran  | 75    |
-----------------
```

But the actual result does not return any rows as it is considering the sub query as a single field.

How can this be handled ?

Comment: or This: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18770581/oracle-split-multiple-comma-separated-values-in-oracle-table-to-multiple-rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of a `listagg` analytical function is text data. Thus, even if you think you are getting

```
'Jon','Rob','Bran'
```

as the output, it is actually a single string like

```
'''Jon'', ''Rob'', ''Bran'''
```

For your purpose the answer by @artm should suffice. Otherwise, if you're bound to do what you're trying to do then you will need to use dynamic SQL like this:

```
declare
    p_cur sys_refcursor;
    name_list clob;
    select_sql clob;
begin
    select listagg(''''||Name||'''', ',')
               within group (order by Name) as name_list
      into name_list
      from STUDENTS;

    select_sql := 'select * from result where name in (' || name_list || ')';

    open p_cur for select_sql;
end;
/
```