# How to Pass Comma String as Single String in IN Clause

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm writing a SQL code using an IN operator. It is working good unless I encountered some records having comma in the strings.

This is where I am failing to fetch those records.
For example -: 'Pratik,Sarangi' is a record i want to pass in the IN clause where in it reads as 2 different datas.

I am using Oracle SQL to build the query

select * from table where name in (:name)

where :name is a user input parameter.

Comment: This suggests you're doing something rather worrying with your query - a correctly secured application should completely separate the input from query, no matter what punctuation it contains. Perhaps if you [edit] your question to show the code where you create the SQL we will be able to see why it's happening. Please also mention which language and database you're using,

Comment: I am sorry about that. Let me edit my question and re post it. I was using SQL

Comment: I just updated the Question as suggested by @IMsoP. I am using Oracle DB

Comment: You need to convert your string into an array. There are many threads on how to achieve this with Oracle, and there are several different approaches. [This answer is the best summary of the different options](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38372145/146325)

Comment: Please, add your current query and the expected output/s.