# converting a column result in to multiple row in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, split, delimiter

I have `material_info` table in oracle db

```
MATERIAL    COUNTRIES
----------------------------
HX345TY     US,IN,SG,CN,JP
MXT15WO     SL,AU,IN,US,AF
UIY7890#RT  UK,US,IN,SG,PK
```

i want output as below

```
MATERIAL    COUNTRIES
-----------------------------
HX345TY     US
HX345TY     IN
HX345TY     SG
HX345TY     CN
HX345TY     JP
MXT15WO     SL
MXT15WO     AU
MXT15WO     IN
MXT15WO     US
MXT15WO     AF
UIY7890#RT  UK
UIY7890#RT  US
UIY7890#RT  IN
UIY7890#RT  SG
UIY7890#RT  PK
```

I wrote the query for this like below. but it is  not working. Can anyone give the solutions

```
select material, trim(regexp_substr(COUNTRIES,'[^,]+', 1, level) ) COUNTRIES, level
from material_info connect by regexp_substr(COUNTRIES, '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null;
```

Comment: You shouldn't be storing comma separated values in a single column to begin with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should prefer [`prior + sys_guid`](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2526535)  technique. It is far efficient than distinct for large number of records.

```
select material,
       regexp_substr(countries, '[^,]+', 1, level) countries
  from material_info
connect by level <= regexp_count(countries, '[^,]+')
and prior material = material
and prior sys_guid() is not null;
```

[**DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=67008b00c2634c8051217c4952257f92)

Comment: if i want to conditionally filter the query with material then what will be the query.

let say i want to filter with 'material' = 'UIY7890#RT'

Comment: Why should "you prefer" this technique? There are [faster methods that do not use regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38372145/1509264).

Answer (score 0):

You can slightly change by using `distinct`, and `regexp_count` to make dynamic

```
select distinct material,
       regexp_substr(countries, '[^,]+', 1, level) countries
  from material_info
connect by level <= regexp_count(countries, '[^,]+')
order by material;
```

or use `group by material, countries, level` as

```
select material,
       regexp_substr(countries, '[^,]+', 1, level) countries
  from material_info
connect by level <= regexp_count(countries, '[^,]+')
group by material, countries, level;
```

even no need to use `trim`

<kbd>[Demo](https://rextester.com/JNJ26194)</kbd>