# Split CLOB column based on new line - Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I have a table

table1

```
f_name     f_content
test1.txt  YL*1**50*1~
           RX*1~
           LR*2~
test2.txt  YL*1**49*1~
           EE*1~
           WW*2~
```

- f_content is CLOB
- f_name is varchar2 (4000)

I have written this SQL:

```
SELECT
    d.*,
    c.line_num,
    translate(substr(d.f_content, part1 + 1, part2 - part1), ' ~'
                                                                || CHR(10)
                                                                || CHR(13), ' ') line
FROM
    table1 d
    CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
        SELECT
            level   line_num,
            DECODE(level, 1, 0, regexp_instr(d.f_content, '~', 1, level - 1)) part1,
            DECODE(regexp_instr(d.f_content, '~', 1, level), 0, length(d.f_content), regexp_instr(d.f_content, '~', 1, level
            )) part2
        FROM
            dual
        CONNECT BY
            level <= regexp_count(d.f_content, '~ ')
    ) c;
```

My expected output is:

```
f_name     f_content        line_num    line
test1.txt  YL*1**50*1~      1           YL*1**50*1
           RX*1~
           LR*2~
test1.txt  YL*1**50*1~      2           RX*1
           RX*1~
           LR*2~
test1.txt  YL*1**50*1~      3           LR*2
           RX*1~
           LR*2~


test2.txt  YL*1**49*1~      1           YL*1**49*1
           EE*1~
           WW*2~
test2.txt  YL*1**49*1~      2           EE*1
           EE*1~
           WW*2~
test2.txt  YL*1**49*1~      3           WW*2
           EE*1~
           WW*2~
```

However in the output based on the SQL above, I am only getting line_num = 1.

How can I get the SQL code working so it gives all the lines?

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38372145/7998591)'s a good answer with discussions on the performance of various solutions to the problem. Do take a look at other answers as well. If possible compare the performance of those solutions with your data to arrive at a better solution to suit your needs.

Comment: @KaushikNayak - I read the above answer. I want to create a new table using this. Is there a way to make execution faster? Add parallel hints?

Comment: So, you want create a new table to store the values separately using the output of the query  or store values separated by `~` in a single column? If the latter is true then I would suggest you not to go ahead with it. If you could control the data at source to make  it more structured( to be able to store the values separately ) as relational database rules recommend, you'll be in a better position to optimize queries on any volume of data, given enough resources. Without that, a Hint would do no good as an unstructured data is still harder to be retrieved.

Comment: I want to create new table to store the values from the output of the SQL query.

Comment: Moreover, `CLOB`s are generally slower than normal character types( `VARCHAR2`). So, there is something fundamentally wrong in the way data is stored. As I mentioned, Instead of having entire unstructured data(`f_content`)  as a `CLOB` column, you could very well have  received it as a standard CSV or XML or JSON formats, with an agreed upon pre-defined structure .You would then have several built-in functions/ APIs to extract the required data efficiently. It is really sub-optimal to store them as `CLOB` and then try to transform it from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `hierarchical query` without a `JOIN` condition :

```
select t1.*, level as line_num, 
       regexp_replace( regexp_substr( t1.f_content,'[^~]+', 1, level), '(^[[:space:]]+)' ) 
       as line
  from table1 t1
 connect by level <= regexp_count(f_content, '~')   
    and prior f_name = f_name
    and prior sys_guid() is not null
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://rextester.com/AUW72373)</kbd>

Comment: I have over 30K records with more than 1000 lines in each. Would this query be faster?

Comment: @dang I didn't test, I don't know dear Dhananjay.

Comment: Ok, how can I remove trailing and leading spaces?

Comment: Also, should I be considering CHR(10) and CHR(13) characters?

Comment: you can replace `replace(t1.f_content,' ')` with `t1.f_content` inside `regexp_substr` expression. And we don't need CHR(10) or CHR(13).

Comment: It will replace all the spaces in the string. I just want to replace trailing and leading spaces.

Comment: @dang : To replace trailing and leading spaces, simply using `TRIM` function should work.

Comment: @KaushikNayak it's interesting but TRIM doesn't work even used as `trim(leading ' ' from t1.f_content)`. Because of this, I considered `regexp_replace( ... , '(^[[:space:]]+)' )`

Comment: Well, then it's not a space character, should be something else.

Comment: Can I add parallel hints OR partitioning to speed this up?

Comment: I'm basically doing a create table as and it is taking long time to write it. Not sure if there is a way to improve performance.

Comment: @dang do you want to make spesific text search inside CLOB, why do you need performance?

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan - I am splitting CLOB to multiple rows separated by *. For ex. ABC*01*34 need to become 3 rows with values - ABC, 01, 34. So, first step is breaking it down by lines and I want to store it in a table. Then the next step is to break those lines into separate rows. While writing to separate lines using the SQL query as per above, it is taking long time to create table. So, I am wondering if there is a way to write faster.

Comment: @dang perhaps, creating an `ctxsys.context` type index on `f_content` column to improve query performance.

Comment: Can you tell me how to create this index?

Comment: @dang `create index idx_tab1_fcontent on table1(f_content)
      indextype is ctxsys.context`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192841/discussion-between-barbaros-ozhan-and-dang).