# Parse value delimited from both sides of it into multiple rows

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, split

I have a column value that is like this

`#123##456##789#*0123*`, (each value is parsed on both sides) and I want to parse it to look like this:

```
id value type
1 123     #
1 456     #
1 789     #
1 0123    *
```

How should I do it?

**Bonus question**, I want to pass id in the query, and the parser should know the column that it should parse (I don't want to parse static value), how would that query look like. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have access to any other tools besides Oracle?  This is a data scrubbing problem, and a a database is not really the best place to be doing this.

Comment: Well, I should write a script that fills a table with values based on this column, I should do everything in oracle sql.

Comment: If you really want to do this in Oracle, you might need to write a stored procedure.

Comment: Do the values only have digits? And also, is always the type in `*`, `#` ? The second question is not that clear to me, can you please post some sample data and needed result?

Comment: Check out this related question for some good answers about this general class of problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38371989/how-to-convert-comma-separated-values-to-rows-in-oracle

Comment: It definitely should be a procedure, my first step should be this parsing before I can do anything.

Comment: @Aleksej yes, inbetween are only numbers. Sample data for bonus question 
column1(id)|column2(value)
1  |  #123##254#*78*

If value that need to be parsed has id of 1, than parse column2. Thanks

Comment: @kfinity thanks, I will check it out.

Comment: @Aleksej and also yes, types are only # and *

Comment: @kfinity I checked that out, the problem that i face is that values are delimited from both sides. After I parse the values, I want to be left with only numbers

Comment: What is the purpose of the id column if it is always 1?

Comment: please show your effort, and what you have tried so far ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I modified [MT0's recursive CTE answer from the link above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38371989/how-to-convert-comma-separated-values-to-rows-in-oracle) to handle two delimiters (ie, on both ends), and to pull out the delimiter into a separate column. Let me know if you have any questions.

```
with example as (select 1 as id, '#123##456##789#*0123*' as str from dual
                union select 2, '#837#*827*#3021#*013*' from dual),
  t ( id, str, start_pos, end_pos ) AS
    ( SELECT id, str, 1, REGEXP_INSTR( str, '[^0-9]' ) FROM example
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id,
      str,
      end_pos                    + 1,
      REGEXP_INSTR( str, '[^0-9]', end_pos + 1 )
    FROM t
    WHERE end_pos > 0
    )
SELECT id, 
  --str, start_pos, end_pos, -- uncomment for debugging
  SUBSTR( str, start_pos, DECODE( end_pos, 0, LENGTH( str ) + 1, end_pos ) - start_pos ) AS value,
  substr(str, start_pos-1, 1) as type
FROM t
where start_pos <> end_pos and end_pos <> 0
  -- bonus question - uncomment to filter by ID
  --and id = 1
ORDER BY id,
  start_pos;
```

FYI - this will drop null values (eg "##") and not display them as a row.

Comment: Thank you so much, you did what I asked for and even more than that!