# oracle regular expression substring question

Tags: oracle, regexp-substr

I am struggling to come up with a regular expression which extracts everything with the pattern between "abc_" and "&"

```
Example 1: 

Input string: abc_s=facebook&abc_m=social&abc_c=abcd-video&clicks=jfhjkfdjfdjkfh

Output string: abc_s=facebook&abc_m=social&abc_c=abcd-video

Example 2: 

input string: abc_s=facebook&abc_m=social&gmpc_c=abcd-ideo&clicks=jfhjkfdjfdjkfh

output string: abc_s=facebook&abc_m=social&
```

any ideas on how to achieve this...i looked at the documentation but its not very clear for me as to how to use regexp_substr function to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it using combination of `instr` and `substr` as following:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(INPUT_STR,
              1, INSTR(SUBSTR(INPUT_STR, (INSTR(INPUT_STR, 'abc_', -1) + 4)), '&')) AS OUTPUT_STR
FROM YOUR_TABLE
```

Try it and let me know if it works for you?

Cheers!!

Comment: basically i want to extract the entire string with the pattern abc_ until the last & (exclude the last &) if the abc_& is repeated 2 times then i want to extract that part which abc_w=123&abc_x=256 and if the abc_& is repeated 4 times i want to extract all the abc_w=123&abc_x=123&abc_y=123&abc_z=123 and the string may contain any other additional values which simply needs to be discarded. You solution isn't working :(

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to do a substr from "the first 'abc_'"  to "the first '&' that isn't followed by 'abc_'". For the beginning part, a regular `INSTR` will work; for the end condition, you'll need a regexp.

```
set scan off
-- example data
with x as (select 'abc_s=facebook&abc_m=social&abc_c=abcd-video&clicks=jfhjkfdjfdjkfh' as s from dual
           union select 'abc_s=facebook&abc_m=social&gmpc_c=abcd-ideo&clicks=jfhjkfdjfdjkfh' from dual
           union select 'www.google.com/search?abc_source=blah&abc_medium=blahblah&abc_campaign=blahblah' from dual)
-- query
SELECT SUBSTR(s,
              INSTR(s, 'abc_'), -- start with the first 'abc_'
              regexp_instr(s, '(&[^a][^b][^c][^_])|$')-1 -- end with the first & that isn't followed by "abc_"; or the end
              ) AS OUTPUT_STR
FROM x;
```

Output:

```
abc_s=facebook&abc_m=social&abc_c=abcd-video                      
abc_s=facebook&abc_m=social
abc_source=blah&abc_medium=blahblah&abc_campaign=blahblah
```

As a side note, if you're trying to split the '&'-separated values into a list, [try looking at one of the questions about splitting comma-separated values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38371989/how-to-convert-comma-separated-values-to-rows-in-oracle), but use & instead of a comma.

Comment: i want to exact the entire string with the pattern abc_ and the delimiter is &. I tried your solution and its not giving the results i want.

Comment: Maybe you could edit your question to show the results you want?

Comment: basically i want to extract the entire string with the pattern abc_ until the last & (exclude the last &) if the abc_& is repeated 2 times then i want to extract that part which abc_w=123&abc_x=256 and  if the abc_& is repeated 4 times i want to extract all the abc_w=123&abc_x=123&abc_y=123&abc_z=123 and the string may contain any other additional values which simply needs to be discarded.

Comment: Can you give me an example string where my query doesn't do what you want?

Comment: could u try for this url

Comment: input string: www.google.com/search?abc_source=blah&abc_medium=blahblah&abc_campaign=blahblah

expected output string: abc_source=blah&abc_medium=blahblah&abc_campaign=blahblah

Comment: actually the last word may or may not contain & since that is the end of the string. My bad i dint specify this clearly.

Comment: Oh, of course! I updated the regexp to look for either "&nonabcstring" or the end of the string.