# Count how many times distinct words appear in a column Oracle 12c SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

How can you count how many times all the distinct words in a column appear

Below is an example and expected output

```
+--------+------------------------------+
| PERIOD |            STRING            |
+--------+------------------------------+
|        |                              |
| 1      | this is some text            |
|        |                              |
| 2      | more text                    |
|        |                              |
| 3      | this could be some more text |
+--------+------------------------------+

+-------+-------+
| WORD  | COUNT |
+-------+-------+
|       |       |
| this  | 2     |
|       |       |
| is    | 1     |
|       |       |
| some  | 2     |
|       |       |
| text  | 3     |
|       |       |
| more  | 2     |
|       |       |
| could | 1     |
|       |       |
| be    | 1     |
+-------+-------+
```

Thanks,

Comment: Do you want to do this in pure SQL, or can you use language like PL/SQL ?

Comment: Either, Can use PL/SQL for a solution as well as SQL

Comment: btw, having capital letters vs. small letters such as `This` vs. `this` matter ? eg. are both equal or not?

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan Cases does not matter so both would be equal

Comment: Almost a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/38371989/1509264 just with an added `COUNT` step at the end.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Hierarchical query such as

```
WITH t2 AS
(
 SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(LOWER(string),'[^[:space:]]+',1,level) AS word
   FROM t  
CONNECT BY level <= REGEXP_COUNT(LOWER(string),'[:space:]') + 1
    AND PRIOR SYS_GUID() IS NOT NULL
    AND PRIOR period = period
)    
SELECT word, COUNT(*) AS count
  FROM t2
 WHERE word IS NOT NULL
 GROUP BY word
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=5d4774e9718714763b46afe2bd6d1b78)</kbd>

*P.S. `LOWER()` function is applied in order to get rid of problem related to case-sensitivity.*

Answer (score 0):

The trick is splitting the string into words.  One method uses a recursive CTE:

```
with words(word, string, n) as (
      select regexp_substr(string, '[^ ]+', 1, 1) as word, string, 1 as n
      from t
      union all
      select regexp_substr(string, '[^ ]+', 1, n + 1), string, n + 1
      from words
      where regexp_substr(string, '[^ ]+', 1, n + 1) is not null
     )
select word, count(*)
from words
group by word;
```

[Here](http://%20https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ae4b04070939c2073446c80e50ee7aea) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without (slow) regular expressions using simple string functions:

```sql
WITH word_bounds ( string, start_pos, end_pos ) AS (
  SELECT string,
         1,
         INSTR( string, ' ', 1 )
  FROM   table_name
UNION ALL
  SELECT string,
         end_pos + 1,
         INSTR( string, ' ', end_pos + 1 )
  FROM   word_bounds
  WHERE  end_pos > 0
),
words ( word ) AS (
SELECT CASE end_pos
       WHEN 0
       THEN SUBSTR( string, start_pos )
       ELSE SUBSTR( string, start_pos, end_pos - start_pos )
       END
FROM   word_bounds
)
SELECT word,
       COUNT(*) AS frequency
FROM   words
GROUP BY
       word
ORDER BY
       frequency desc, word;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( PERIOD, STRING ) AS
SELECT 1, 'this is some text' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'more text' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'this could be some more text' FROM DUAL
```

Outputs:

> ```
> WORD  | FREQUENCY
> :---- | --------:
> text  |         3
> more  |         2
> some  |         2
> this  |         2
> be    |         1
> could |         1
> is    |         1
> ```

There is a discussion on the performance of different ways of splitting delimited strings [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38372145/1509264).

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ddbdc070a88a356bafea4a32709c2be5)*