# BigQuery: Counting how many of each distinct word appears in a list of titles

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have been trying to run a query that will return a count of how many times each unique word appears in a column of titles. I tried the option in [THIS POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64969156/count-how-many-times-distinct-words-appear-in-a-column-oracle-12c-sql) but consistently got an error message:

"Table "word_count" must be qualified with a dataset (e.g. dataset.table)."

word_count is a CTE (example below) so I am not sure what the issue is. Any help is appreciated.

```
WITH word_count AS (
  SELECT Title,
         1,
         INSTR(Title, ' ', 1 )
  FROM   `circulation2023.top_food`
UNION ALL
  SELECT Title,
         end_pos + 1,
         INSTR(Title, ' ', end_pos + 1 )
  FROM   word_count
  WHERE  end_pos > 0
),
words AS (
SELECT CASE end_pos
       WHEN 0
       THEN SUBSTR(Title, start_pos )
       ELSE SUBSTR(Title, start_pos, end_pos - start_pos )
       END
FROM   word_count
)
SELECT word,
       COUNT(*) AS frequency
FROM   words
GROUP BY
       word
ORDER BY
       frequency desc, word;
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error suggests you are missing the `dataset` part of the table reference. In the case of. `` FROM `circulation2023.top_food `` this would be the `circulation2023` part.

Should look like this

```
SELECT Title,
         1,
         INSTR(Title, ' ', 1 )
  FROM   `circulation2023.top_food`
UNION ALL
  SELECT Title,
         end_pos + 1,
         INSTR(Title, ' ', end_pos + 1 )
  FROM   `dataset.word_count`
  WHERE  end_pos > 0
```

Also, it is recommended to avoid circular references to tables, eg if the source table is `word_count` do not also name the CTE `word_count`.
At the very least it makes it unclear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: But there is no word_count in the source table. word_count is only a CTE. There is no dataset to reference.

Comment: The intention is for `word_count` to be a recursive CTE but the error leads me to believe that the query is treating that reference as through it is a regular table and therefore needs  to be qualified with a dataset.