# Row-Level Security Predicate Filter

Tags: sql, oracle, csv, sql-like, row-level-security

On Oracle 19c.

We have users whose accounts are provisioned by specifying a comma separated list of `department_code` values.  Each of the `department_code` values is a string of five alpha-numeric [A-Z0-9] characters.  This comma separated value list of five character `department_code`s is what we call the user's `security_string`.  We use this `security_string` to limit which rows the user may retrieve from a table, `Restricted`, by applying the following predicate.

```sql
select *
from Restricted R
where :security_string like '%' || R.department_code || '%';
```

A given `department_code` can be in `Restricted` many times and a given user can have many `department_code`s in their comma-separated value `:security_string`.

This predicate approach to applying row-level security is inefficient.  No index can be used and it requires a full table scan on `Restricted`.

In alternative is to use dynamic SQL to do something like as follows.

```sql
execute immediate 'select *
from Restricted R
where R.department_code in(' || udf_quoted_values(:security_string) || ')';
```

Where `udf_quoted_values` is a user-defined function (UDF) that wraps in single quotes each `department_code` value within the `:security_string`.
However, this alternative approach also seems unsatisfactory as it requires a UDF, dynamic sql, and a full table scan is still likely.

I've considered bit-masking, but the number of bits needed is large 60 million (=36^5) and it would still require a UDF, dynamic sql, and a full table scan (function based index doesn't seem to be a candidate here).  Also, bit-masking doesn't make much sense here as there is no nesting/hierarchy of `department_code`s.

```sql
execute immediate 'select *
from Restricted R
where BITAND(R.department_code_encoded,' || udf_encoded_number(:security_string) || ') > 0';
```

Where `Restricted.department_code_encoded` is a numeric encoded value of `Restricted.department_code` and `udf_encoded_number` is a user-defined function (UDF) that returns a number encoding the `department_code`s in the `:security_string`.

I've considered creating a separate table of just department codes, `Department`, and joining that to the `Restricted` table.

```sql
select *
from Restricted R
join Department D
on R.deparment_code = D.department_code
where :security_string like '%' || D.department_code || '%';
```

We still have the same problems as before, but now it is on the smaller (table cardinality) `Department` table (`Department.department_code` is unique where as `Restricted.department_code` is not unique).  This provides for a smaller full table scan on `Department` than on `Restricted`, but now we have a join.

It is possible for us to change `security_string` or add additional user specific security values when the account is provisioned.  We can also change the Oracle objects and queries.  Note, the `department_code`s are not static, but don't change all that regularly either.

Any recommendations?  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Why not converting the string to a table, like suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38371989/how-to-convert-comma-separated-values-to-rows-in-oracle), and then do a join.