# String split which will guaranteed the order of string in which it's passed

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, sql-server-2012, oracle10g

I am stuck with one of issue where I need to ensure split of string which will guaranteed the order of split string in which its passed .
Example : string = "a,b,c,d,e"

After split expected guaranteed order result :
Please see the attached image for result .

I seen many ans which will give me split of string but as we know temp table will not guaranteed the order of string . I need this for both SQL 2012 or higher,Oracle 10g should be working .[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are not going to find a single query that does this for both SQL Server and Oracle as, among many other reasons, their string-parsing functions have different names.

For Oracle, there are lots of solutions in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38371989/1509264); however, they mostly will not work on Oracle 10g as they rely on improvements that were introduced in 11g or 12c. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38373452/1509264) should be able to be adapted to [hopefully] make it work in Oracle 10g (but I have nowhere to test it as Oracle 10g is *very* old now and you should really be looking to upgrade to a newer version):

```sql
SELECT t.value,
       v.COLUMN_VALUE AS item
FROM   table_name t
       CROSS JOIN TABLE(
         CAST(
           MULTISET(
             SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR( t.value, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL )
             FROM   DUAL
             CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR( t.value, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL ) IS NOT NULL
           )
           AS SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST
         )
       ) v
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE TABLE_NAME ( value ) AS
SELECT 'a,b,c,d,e' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | VALUE | ITEM |
> | --- | --- |
> | a,b,c,d,e | a |
> | a,b,c,d,e | b |
> | a,b,c,d,e | c |
> | a,b,c,d,e | d |
> | a,b,c,d,e | e |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=062713c689ed115f7a4ed17782a54c00)*