# Oracle regexp_substr returning different result in case of same varchar

Tags: sql, oracle

Here is the varchar **50% REC.PES/50% PTT** that I have in the `RFDGENERIC` table.

The task is split by `/`.

Here is the query

```
select
    regexp_substr(DESCR, '[^/]+', 1, level) value
from 
    RFDGENERIC 
where 
    id = 14966150
    connect by level <= length(DESCR) - length(replace(DESCR, '/')) + 1
             and prior DESCR = DESCR
             and prior sys_guid() is not null;
```

But the result is.

```
50% REC.PES
50% PTT
50% PTT
```

If I will create the table and insert into it the same value from `RFDGENERIC` the result will be correct.

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_SPLIT
(
    ID NUMBER(20),
    DESCR VARCHAR2(128 char)
);

INSERT INTO TEST_SPLIT (id, DESCR)
    SELECT id, DESCR 
    FROM RFDGENERIC 
    WHERE DESCR = '50% REC.PES/50% PTT' 
      AND id = 14966150;

SELECT
    regexp_substr(DESCR, '[^/]+', 1, level) value
FROM
    TEST_SPLIT 
WHERE
    id = 14966150
      connect by level <= length(DESCR) - length(replace(DESCR, '/')) + 1
             and prior DESCR = DESCR
             and prior sys_guid() is not null;
```

In this case the result is correct:

```
50% REC.PES
50% PTT
```

Notes:

1. All data types are the same.
2. I have used other methods as described [here](https://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2014/12/02/split-comma-delimited-string-into-rows-in-oracle/). Same result.
3. DBMS:

   ```
    Oracle (ver. Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 
    19.0.0.0.0 - Production Version 19.15.0.0.0)

    Case sensitivity: plain=upper, delimited=exact
    Driver: Oracle JDBC driver (ver. 21.5.0.0.0, JDBC4.3)
   ```

Here is the question what is the difference?

Why in the first case I am getting the wrong result?

Comment: What do you get if you run `select count(*) from RFDGENERIC where id = 14966150` ? One possibility is that there are TWO rows in the table, one with the DESCR you shared with us and the other just with DESCR of `50% PTT`. Perhaps that's not the issue, but either way, it should very easy to tell - either that it is, or that it isn't. Of course, when you copy to your TEST_TABLE, you are copying based on the full string in DESCR, so that would be irrelevant (if my speculation is correct).

Comment: I see you selected a "correct answer" that doesn't have anything to do with your question. Do you care to explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get the same result using both queries in 21cXE; don't have 19c to try it on that version.

---

Anyway, perhaps you should switch to

```
SQL> with test_split (id, descr) as
  2    (select 14966150, '50% REC.PES/50% PTT' from dual)
  3  select regexp_substr(descr, '[^/]+', 1, column_value) val
  4  from test_split cross join
  5    table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
  6                        connect by level <= regexp_count(descr, '/') + 1
  7                       ) as sys.odcinumberlist));

VAL
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
50% REC.PES
50% PTT

SQL>
```

which is different from yours as it takes care about potential duplicates in the table (you could "fix" that by adding the `DISTINCT` to your query, but that's not really a solution); also, it kind of *simplifies* the `where` clause (you don't need `prior` and `sys_guid`, unless I'm wrong).

Comment: You get "the same result" on what data? The OP described the problem to us, but didn't tell us anything about the data. If you read my comment under the OP's question, you will see one possible source of the issue.

Comment: I understood that "data" is this, @mathguy: "Here is the varchar 50% REC.PES/50% PTT"

Answer (score 1):

As [@mathguy commented](/questions/72971864/oracle-regexp-substr-returning-different-result-in-case-of-same-varchar#comment128885734_72971864), you only get that result if you have two rows in the table with the same `ID`:

```sql
CREATE TABLE rfdgeneric (id, descr) AS
SELECT 14966150, '50% REC.PES/50% PTT' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 14966150, '50% PTT' FROM DUAL;
```

Then your query outputs:

> | VALUE |
> | --- |
> | 50% PTT |
> | 50% REC.PES |
> | 50% PTT |

Which is as it should for that sample data.

However, there are [many methods of splitting strings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38371989/1509264) and you can use simple string functions that are much faster than regular expressions:

```sql
WITH bounds (descr, spos, epos) AS (
  SELECT descr,
         1,
         INSTR(descr, '/', 1)
  FROM   rfdgeneric
  WHERE  id = 14966150
UNION ALL
  SELECT descr,
         epos + 1,
         INSTR(descr, '/', epos + 1)
  FROM   bounds
  WHERE  epos > 0
)
SELECT CASE epos
       WHEN 0
       THEN SUBSTR(descr, spos)
       ELSE SUBSTR(descr, spos, epos - spos)
       END AS descr
FROM   bounds;
```

Which has the same output:

> | DESCR |
> | --- |
> | 50% REC.PES |
> | 50% PTT |
> | 50% PTT |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=46a8ecc84f958e44dbfc620c02e9984b)*