# Oracle String Replace With Multiple Values

Tags: sql, oracle

I have one key/value comma separated string, and another keys-labels comma separated string as per the following example (ID/Name/Age):

```
key/value:    1=101,2=John,3=43

keys labels:  ID,Name,Age

Result:       ID=101,Name=John,Age=43
```

Is there a built in Oracle function (ex:regexp_replace) that can accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a simple function, no. `regexp_replace` only replaces one value at a time, so to replace 3 values in a string, you need to loop over it 3 times.

It's possible to [split the strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38371989/how-to-convert-comma-separated-values-to-rows-in-oracle), use a `connect by` loop to replace each value, and then put the pairs back together, but it is a bit awkward. Example:

```
with t as (select '1=101,2=John,3=43' as pairs, 'ID,Name,Age' as labels from dual)
select
    listagg(
    regexp_replace(regexp_substr(pairs, '[^,]+', 1, level),
                   '\d+(.+)',
                   regexp_substr(labels, '[^,]+', 1, level) || '\1')
    ,',') 
from t
connect by regexp_substr(pairs, '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null
```

See the link above for how to modify this query for a table with multiple rows and a unique key ID.

Answer (score 0):

if the key values and labels length  are fixed then you can get the result with replace function itself

```
select REPLACE(REPLACE( REPLACE('1=101,2=John,3=43', '1=','ID='),'2=','Name=') ,'3=','Age=') as finresult from dual ;
```

OUTPUT:

```
FINRESULT
ID=101,Name=John,Age=43
```