# Matching strings between columns based on position

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a view that aggregates data about customers and shows the products they have access to, along with the status of whether they use those products on a trial basis or not (both as string comma seperated values):

```
+----------+----------+-----------------------+
| customer | products | products_trial_status |
+----------+----------+-----------------------+
|   234253 | A,B,C    | false,true,false      |
|   923403 | A,C      | true,true             |
|   123483 | B        | true                  |
|   239874 | B,C      | false,false           |
+----------+----------+-----------------------+
```

and I would like to write a query that returns a list of customers who are using a certain product on a trial.

e.g. I want to see which customers using product B are on a trial, I would get something like this:

```
+----------+
| customer |
+----------+
|   234253 | 
|   123483 |
+----------+
```

The only way I can think of doing this is by checking the `products` column for the position of the product in the string (if it exists there), then checking the corresponding value at the same position in the `products_trial_status` column and whether it is equal to true.

i.e. for customer 234253, product B is in position 2 (after the first comma), so it's corresponding trial status in the column would also be in position 2 after the first comma there.

How would I go about doing this?

I am aware that storing such data as a string of values is not good practice but it is not something i can change, so would need to work out using the format it is in

Comment: I would suggest converting comma separated values to rows for both columns then you can use a simple where clause to get what you need.
Refer to this for comma separated to row conversion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38371989/how-to-convert-comma-separated-values-to-rows-in-oracle

Answer (score 2):

You could split the string but it will be quicker to do some (fairly hideous) string manipulations and

- Replace your comma-delimited true/false string with a non-delimited string of 1s and 0s.
- Count the number of terms before the `B` term by counting the number of preceding commas.
- Return the appropriate substring of your 1/0 list.

Like this:

```sql
SELECT customer,
       COALESCE(
         SUBSTR(
           status,
           LENGTH(preceding_terms) - COALESCE(LENGTH(REPLACE(preceding_terms, ',')), 0),
           1
         ),
         '0'
       ) AS hasB
FROM   (
  SELECT customer,
         SUBSTR(','||products, 1, INSTR(','||products||',', ',B,')) AS preceding_terms,
         TRANSLATE(products_trial_status, 'tfrueals,', '10') AS status
  FROM   table_name
)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( customer, products, products_trial_status ) AS
SELECT 234253, 'A,B,C', 'false,true,false' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 923403, 'A,C',   'true,true'        FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 123483, 'B',     'true'             FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 239874, 'B,C',   'false,false'      FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| CUSTOMER | HASB |
| --- | --- |
| 234253 | 1 |
| 923403 | 0 |
| 123483 | 1 |
| 239874 | 0 |

---

If you only want the customer numbers then you can add filters:

```sql
SELECT customer
FROM   (
  SELECT customer,
         SUBSTR(','||products, 1, INSTR(','||products||',', ',B,')) AS preceding_terms,
         TRANSLATE(products_trial_status, 'tfrueals,', '10') AS status
  FROM   table_name
  WHERE  INSTR(','||products||',', ',B,') > 0
)
WHERE   SUBSTR(
           status,
           LENGTH(preceding_terms) - COALESCE(LENGTH(REPLACE(preceding_terms, ',')), 0),
           1
         ) = '1'
```

Which outputs:

| CUSTOMER |
| --- |
| 234253 |
| 123483 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/el_QU3SA)

Comment: This is a very elegant solution without any regular expressions and splitting. Especially for `true/false` -> `1/0`. Thank you for this trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can use hierarchical query in which split the strings by commas and count the number of commas along with regular expression functions such as

```
WITH t1 AS
(
 SELECT customer,
        REGEXP_SUBSTR(products,'[^,]',1,level) AS products,
        REGEXP_SUBSTR(products_trial_status,'[^,]+',1,level) AS products_ts
   FROM t -- your data source
CONNECT BY level <= REGEXP_COUNT(products,',')+1
    AND PRIOR customer = customer
    AND PRIOR sys_guid() IS NOT NULL  
)
SELECT customer
  FROM t1
 WHERE products = 'B'
   AND products_ts = 'true'
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/J03hNKrs)</kbd>