# Use Oracle PL/SQL For Loop to iterate through comma delimited string

Tags: oracle, for-loop, plsql

I am writing a piece of code that would need to iterate on the content of a string, each values being separated with a `,`.

e.g. I have my `elements`

```
v_list_pak_like varchar2(4000) := 'PEBO,PTGC,PTTL,PTOP,PTA';
```

### How can I get it into an Array / Cursor to iterate on it in my loop?

```
for x in (elements)
loop
   -- do my stuff
end loop;
```

I am looking for the very simple way, if possible avoiding to declare associative arrays.

**Would it be possible to create a function** that would return something usable as an input for a `for` loop (opposite to the while that could be used like in https://stackoverflow.com/a/19184203/6019417)?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to loop through a delimited list in Oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19168819/how-to-loop-through-a-delimited-list-in-oracle)

Comment: But why PL/SQL when you could do it in plain SQL? See [**Split comma delimited string into rows**](https://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2014/12/02/split-comma-delimited-string-into-rows-in-oracle/)

Comment: Thanks, that would be my second choice to use `instr` inside a `while`. Is it possible to use a function which would return something usable inside a `for` loop.

Comment: Thank you @Lalit, I think this will help me a lot.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You could do it easily in pure **SQL**. there are multiple ways of doing it, see **[Split comma delimited string into rows in Oracle](https://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2014/12/02/split-comma-delimited-string-into-rows-in-oracle/)**

However, if you really want to do it in **PL/SQL**, then you could do it as:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> DECLARE
  2    str VARCHAR2(100) := 'PEBO,PTGC,PTTL,PTOP,PTA';
  3  BEGIN
  4    FOR i IN
  5    (SELECT trim(regexp_substr(str, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL)) l
  6    FROM dual
  7      CONNECT BY LEVEL <= regexp_count(str, ',')+1
  8    )
  9    LOOP
 10      dbms_output.put_line(i.l);
 11    END LOOP;
 12  END;
 13  /
PEBO
PTGC
PTTL
PTOP
PTA

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: This worked for me. I will ask another more accurate question about the _function_ I am looking for.

Comment: @J.Chomel You can create a user defined function. Or use Oracle's inbuilt package **DBMS_UTILITY**. Let me know if you post a different question, I can help you with an answer.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to Lalit great instructions, I am able to create a function that I can call from my `for` loop:

### Create a type and function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE t_my_list AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(100);
CREATE OR REPLACE
       FUNCTION comma_to_table(p_list IN VARCHAR2)
         RETURN t_my_list
       AS
         l_string VARCHAR2(32767) := p_list || ',';
         l_comma_index PLS_INTEGER;
         l_index PLS_INTEGER := 1;
         l_tab t_my_list     := t_my_list();
       BEGIN
         LOOP
           l_comma_index := INSTR(l_string, ',', l_index);
           EXIT
         WHEN l_comma_index = 0;
           l_tab.EXTEND;
           l_tab(l_tab.COUNT) := TRIM(SUBSTR(l_string,l_index,l_comma_index - l_index));
           l_index            := l_comma_index + 1;
         END LOOP;
         RETURN l_tab;
       END comma_to_table;
/
```

### Then how to call it in my *for* loop:

```
declare
  v_list_pak_like varchar2(4000) := 'PEBO,PTGC,PTTL,PTOP,PTA';
begin
    FOR x IN (select * from (table(comma_to_table(v_list_pak_like)) ) )
    loop
        dbms_output.put_line(x.COLUMN_VALUE);
    end loop;
end;
/
```

Notice the default name `COLUMN_VALUE` given by Oracle that is necessary for the use I want to make of the result.

### Result as expected:

```
PEBO
PTGC
PTTL
PTOP
PTA
```

Comment: Good job, @J. Chomel. This is what I wanted, putting a result in a variable I can loop over. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

```
declare
    type array_type is table of VARCHAR2(255) NOT NULL;
    my_array array_type := array_type('aaa','bbb','ccc');
begin
    for i in my_array.first..my_array.last loop
        dbms_output.put_line( my_array(i) );
    end loop;
end;
```

The first line defines a table of any type you want.

then declare a variable of that type and give its values with a constructor.

Then loop over the result from the first index to the last.

Edit - A solution that handles true string:

```
declare
    str      VARCHAR2(1024) := 'aaa,bbb,ccc';
    type     ARRAY_TYPE is table of VARCHAR2(255) NOT NULL;
    my_array ARRAY_TYPE;
begin
    SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(str, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) BULK COLLECT INTO my_array
    FROM DUAL
    CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(str, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL;

    for i in my_array.first..my_array.last loop
        dbms_output.put_line( my_array(I));
    end loop;
end;
```

Comment: This answer seems good but with some explanations it would be a better answer ;-)

Comment: It's pretty self explanatory :) but ok I added some explanations.

Comment: doesn't seem to iterate through a comma delimited string like 'PEBO,PTGC,PTTL,PTOP,PTA'

Comment: You are right, I didn't see that. Added another step to handle it as a string