# Split comma separated values in Oracle 9i

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle9i

In Oracle, I have columns called orderids

```
orderids
111,222,333
444,55,66
77,77
```

How can get the output as

```
Orderid
111
222
333
444
55
66
77
77
```

Comment: In the future, please spend more time formatting your question. Since you haven't formatted the expected and the actual output, all numbers were on the same line and the question rather misleading. I've fixed it this time.

Comment: If you google for "oracle split string into rows", you'll find what your looking for, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14328621/oracle-10g-splitting-string-into-multiple-rows.

Comment: Nope @Codo, regular expressions were introduced in 10g, which means the usual ways of doing this won't work (which is the reason why I haven't closed).

Comment: Good point. But it can be done with INSTR and SUBSTR as well.

Comment: Yes, and [DBMS_UTILITY.COMMA_TO_TABLE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96612/d_util2.htm#1002109).

Comment: Oracle 9i has been out of support for nearly a decade now. You should really think about upgrading to a supported version (which is 11.x or 12.x)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
 WITH TT AS
 (SELECT orderid COL1 FROM orders)
 SELECT substr(str,
                   instr(str, ',', 1, LEVEL) + 1,
                   instr(str, ',', 1, LEVEL + 1) -
                   instr(str, ',', 1, LEVEL) - 1) COL1
     FROM   (SELECT rownum AS r,
                    ','|| COL1||',' AS STR
               FROM   TT )
     CONNECT BY PRIOR r = r
         AND    instr(str, ',', 1, LEVEL + 1) > 0
         AND    PRIOR dbms_random.STRING('p', 10) IS NOT NULL
;
```

[image]

See this [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c37f9/1)

Comment: i want each word in individual rows

Answer (score 1):

This is one appraoch:

```
with order_table as (
  select '111,222,333' as orderids from dual
  union all select '444,55,66' from dual
  union all select '77,77' from dual
)
select substr(orderids, instr(orderids, ',', 1, lvl) + 1, instr(orderids, ',', 1, lvl + 1) - instr(orderids, ',', 1, lvl) - 1) orderid 
from
  ( select ',' || orderids || ',' as orderids from order_table ),
  ( select level as lvl from dual connect by level <= 100 )
where lvl <= length(orderids) - length(replace(orderids, ',')) - 1;
```

Just remove the WITH clause and replace the `order_table` with your real table.

Answer (score 0):

This too might help you,

```
with t(orderid) as 
(
SELECT '111,222,333' FROM dual
UNION
SELECT '444,55,66' FROM dual
UNION
SELECT '177,77' FROM dual
)
SELECT trim(x.COLUMN_VALUE.EXTRACT('e/text()')) cols 
FROM t t, TABLE (xmlsequence(XMLTYPE('<e><e>' || REPLACE(t.orderid,',','</e><e>')|| '</e></e>').EXTRACT('e/e'))) x;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
instr(','||NVL('972414AQ,972414AQ',I.CUSIP)||',', ','||I.CUSIP||',') > 0
```

This is the actual query I was looking for.