# Make a query to split a line into x line depending on a field

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I got a line in my data base, containing a fields with some names, separated by a `;` .

I am trying to get, with a Select query, as many lines, that there is name in my field.

So, if I got in my DB :

```
id names
1  john;jack;mike
```

With this, i must get with this query :

```
SELECT id, split(names, ';') from table 

1 john
1 jack
1 mike
```

I don't have any other table, so no join.

I write :  split(names, ';'), but this is just an example of what I want to do.

But I don't know how to split my field names to do it like ahead.

I don't found any thing to help me, find a way to do it.

Do I need to use a function? Is there a function to do so with oracle?

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Oracle 10g Splitting string into multiple rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14328621/oracle-10g-splitting-string-into-multiple-rows)

Comment: @PeterLang Almost, but the answer in this other questions does not work for me, while the answer here by BhupeshC fit perfectly, thanks to the prior it seems. The the edit linking a question with uncorrect answer is not really relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT id, TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR( names, '[^;]+', 1, LEVEL)) FROM table_name
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH(REGEXP_REPLACE(names, '[^;]+')) + 1
AND PRIOR id = id
AND PRIOR DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE IS NOT NULL
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b3ff0/1)**

Comment: It is perfect. Can you add please, some explanations for the two last lines, with the `PRIOR` key word?