# Splitting Comma separated values in columns to multiple rows in Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv

My table has three columns. One of the columns [`Col3`] has multiple values. So, when I make a select command on the table :

```
Select col1, col2, col3 from MyTable
```

It gives me the below result:

```
         Col1       Col2         Col3
         ------------------------------
Row 1    430        A319         N1160 N1336
Row 2    abc        efg          G3489 M5678 N5643
```

If there any way to get the output as:

```
         Col1       Col2         Col3
         ------------------------------
Row 1    430        A319         N1160
Row 2    430        A319         N1336
Row 3    abc        efg          G3489
Row 4    abc        efg          M5678
Row 5    abc        efg          N5643
```

Like if the column has multiple values, then a new row is displayed corresponding to each value in the column and other columns should contain the duplicated data.

I hope I am pretty clear with the problem.

Comment: so you want to display `430     A319` if it is null??

Comment: Then NULL will be displayed in those columns

Comment: It seems you misunderstood Ganesh_Devlekar. How do you know that you want to show 430 for col1 in row 2? Is it always 430 for a NULL in col1 and always A319 for a NULL in col2?

Comment: What do you exactly mean by col3 contains multiple values? What is the datatype of col3?

Comment: I think i again do not get the point. My table has a single row and one of the columns has multiple data. Requirement is to get as many rows as the number of multiple values in the column and the other columns should contain the same data(whether any value or Null). I hope it is clear now.

Comment: The column with multiple values : is it comma seperated? Space seperated? if it has value "abcd123" do you want a record for every character?(ie: A , B, C , .. ) ?

Comment: Why does that column store multiple values at all?

Comment: Datatype is nVarchar, and the values are seperated by space. In this sense the values are multiple.

Comment: @Lokesh Provide Some more (>5) rows and Expected output

Comment: What about moving col3 into an 1:n relation table and then do a simple join ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
SELECT col1,
       col2,
       Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') col3
FROM   (SELECT col1,
               col2,
               Cast ('<M>' + Replace(col3, ' ', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data
        FROM   [table]) AS A
       CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
```

Comment: Worked like charm. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Just one more thing, can you add an explanation how the above code is working or any link where i can get the info.

Comment: @Lokesh This should help you.. http://oops-solution.blogspot.in/2011/10/sql-serverhow-to-split-comma-delimited.html

Comment: @Fireblade: Can you pls tell me how to do the same thing it in `Oracle`. I have replaced `CROSS APPLY` with 'CROSS JOIN'. But it is not working

Comment: @Crazy2crack - Oracle does not support Cross Apply and Cross Join is not same as Cross Apply. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14328621/splitting-string-into-multiple-rows-in-oracle

Comment: @Fireblade. Got it. Thank u :)

Comment: @MotoGP is it possible to use this in comma separated too? I tried your method and I get an error : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36182905/transfer-comma-separated-values-in-one-column-to-different-rows-in-mysql

Comment: @RainMan - This answer specific to `SQL Server` will not work with `Mysql`

Comment: How to split multiple columns in this same way. I have tried, but i am failing on this. Please help me on this.                                                                
            Col1       Col2       Col3           Col4
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
Row 1    430      A319   N1160 N1336          78 90
Row 2    abc      efg    G3489 M5678 N5643      109 67 90

Comment: @kasim Post it as a new question along with what have you tried so far.