# SELECT statement where value not from enum

Tags: sql, oracle, validation, enums, db2

I have a varchar column, called `weather`, I would like to validate its values.

The allowed values are from enum. As opposed to a regular enum column- where each time one of the enum values is allowd, this column allows several enum members, separated with a comma.

This is how I validate a simple enum column:

```
select *
from TableName
where weather not in ('SUN', 'RAIN', 'SNOW');
```

The `weather` contains `SUN` or `RAIN` or `SNOW`.

What if the `weather` contains `SNOW,RAIN` or `RAIN,SNOW`?
how can I validate there are only values from enum then?

Any ides? thoughts?

Comment: Why would you allow insertion of such values then?

Comment: @almasshaikh, This is the requirement, I cannot change it. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you not add constraint like 'ADD CONSTRAINT CHK1 CHECK 
(weather IN ('SUN', 'RAIN', 'SNOW'))'

Comment: @almasshaikh, Misundersand. where should I add this constraint? to the DB definition? If yes, I cannot. I only can check values, not more.

Comment: `NORMALIZE` your data first. You should not store multiple `values` in a single `column`.

Comment: What to do if there is a value SUN,CLOUDY

Answer (score 0):

`Like` operator is slow, but maybe on your data can works fast. Try it.

```
select *
from TableName
where (weather not like '%SUN%') and (weather not like '%RAIN%') and (weather not '%SNOW%');
```

Answer (score 0):

This kind of requirement is not RDBMS friendly and [against Codd's 12 Rules](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codd's_12_rules) !!

But still possible.

Simplest elegant solution for you could be a `PL/SQL function`.
It uses an associative array with hold your enum values as key.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION WEATHER_LOOKUP(input_string IN VARCHAR2)
RETURN NUMBER
IS
/* Associative array, can be used like a Map */
TYPE weather_tab IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(20) INDEX BY VARCHAR2(4000);
weathers weather_tab;

temp_weather VARCHAR2(100);

flag NUMBER(1);
BEGIN
   /* Create a Map with your enum values as Key */
    weathers('SNOW') :=1;
    weathers('RAIN') :=2;
    weathers('SUN') :=3;

    /* If it is comma separated, split the tokens.. and iterate */
    FOR I IN 1..REGEXP_COUNT(input_string,',')+1 LOOP
     temp_weather := REGEXP_SUBSTR(input_string,'[^,]+',1,I);
     IF(weathers.EXISTS(temp_weather)) THEN
        flag := 1;
     ELSE
        flag := 0;
        EXIT;
     END IF;  
    END LOOP;

    RETURN flag;

END WEATHER_LOOKUP;
/
```

And your SQL is

```
SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE
where WEATHER_LOOKUP(weather) = 1;
```

Comment: Could you please be more specific about which of Codd's Rules it violates? I am in total agreement with you that data in need of tokenization is cumbersome to work with in Oracle DB.

Comment: It violates the rule of storing more than one piece of data in a field.

Answer (score 0):

> The allowed values are from **enum**. As opposed to a regular enum column- where each time one of the enum values is allowd, **this column allows several enum members**, separated with a comma.

This is *not* an enum, but rather a *set*. Some RDBMS has direct support for that ([like MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/set.html)). But not Oracle (AFAIK). With Oracle the proper way of supporting that would be by using a nested table.

That being said, as if I understand it well, you cannot change your db schema. So, I would go for regular expression in order to solve such case:

```
...
where not regexp_like(weather,'^(((SUN)|(RAIN)|(SNOW))[,$])*');
```

- `^` from start of string
- ( ... )* zero of more occurrence of

  - ((SUN)|(RAIN)|(SNOW)) `SUN` or `RAIN`or `SNOW`
  - `[,$]` followed by a coma or the end of string

This will not check for *duplicate* values though. Was that a requirement?

Comment: I tried this earlier.. but OP needs an `AND` and not `OR` ?? Means check all values(comma seprated) are from list..

Comment: @Maheswaranv I didn't have time to look at this right now -- but as a quick answer to your comment: `not (A or B)` is `(not A) AND (not B)`. OP should definitively take a look at [De Morgan's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws). *This* will probably help her to solve this issue...

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do the trick:

```
… WHERE NOT REGEXP_LIKE(weather, '^((SUN)|(RAIN)|(SNOW))(,((SUN)|(RAIN)|(SNOW)))*$')
```

See [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/39223/0)

Please:

- note, this will allow duplicates, as long as they are valid on their own.
- comment if and as further detail/adjustment is required.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this using `REGEXP_SUBSTR()` and `CONNECT BY` (in Oracle at least - I can't speak for DB2):

```
WITH t1 AS (
    SELECT 1 AS id, 'SUN,RAIN,SNOW' AS weather
      FROM dual
     UNION
    SELECT 2 AS id, 'SUN,RAIN' AS weather
      FROM dual
     UNION
    SELECT 3 AS id, 'SUN,RAIN,SLEET' AS weather
      FROM dual
)
SELECT * FROM (
     SELECT DISTINCT id, weather, REGEXP_SUBSTR(weather, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) AS weather_part
       FROM t1
    CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(weather, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL
) WHERE weather_part NOT IN ('SUN','RAIN','SNOW')
```

See the following thread on StackOverflow for more information on how to split a comma-separated string using `CONNECT BY`:
[Splitting string into multiple rows in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14328621/oracle-10g-splitting-string-into-multiple-rows)