# Split string oracle into a single column and insert into a table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a table with column data in below format(Row# just to indicate row number).

```
Row#1 :test.doc#delimiter#1234,test1.doc#delimiter#1235,test2.doc#delimiter#1236<br>
Row#2 :fil1.txt#delimiter#1456,fil1.txt#delimiter#1457
```

I want to split the string using comma(,) as delimiter, list all in one single column and insert into a new table.

output should be something like this (Row# just to indicate row number):

```
Row#1:test.doc#delimiter#1234<br>
Row#2:test1.doc#delimiter#1235<br>
Row#3:test2.doc#delimiter#1236<br>
Row#4: fil1.txt#delimiter#1456
```

Can anyone help me do this?

Comment: do you want to find each existing delimiter and split in this locations ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Oracle 10g Splitting string into multiple rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14328621/oracle-10g-splitting-string-into-multiple-rows)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WITH data AS (
  SELECT 'test.doc#delimiter#1234,test1.doc#delimiter#1235,test2.doc#delimiter#1236' AS "value" FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'fil1.txt#delimiter#1456,fil1.txt#delimiter#1457' AS "value" FROM DUAL
)
SELECT  REGEXP_SUBSTR( data."value", '[^,]+', 1, levels.COLUMN_VALUE )
FROM    data,
        TABLE(
          CAST(
            MULTISET(
              SELECT LEVEL
              FROM   DUAL
              CONNECT BY  LEVEL <= LENGTH( regexp_replace( "value", '[^,]+'))  + 1
            ) AS sys.OdciNumberList
          )
        ) levels;
```

Comment: @Aramillo The OP states: `(Row# just to indicate row number)`

Answer (score 1):

An easy way would be to, for each row, split the string into multiple rows and insert it to the destination table. There are multiple ways to split a single string into multiple rows on this site. A simple search should give you some answers.

Assuming your table is called origtable, the column that has those strings is called mycol and destination table is called destTable.

```
BEGIN
   FOR orig_row IN (SELECT mycol from origTable) LOOP
      INSERT INTO destTable(outCol)
      SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR (orig_row.mycol,'(.*?)(,|$)',1,LEVEL,NULL,1)
            FROM dual
      CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT (orig_row.mycol, ',') + 1;
   END LOOP;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to find an existing delimier and split it

try this query :

```
select  substr(filed_name ,
               REGEXP_SUBSTR(filed_name,'#demilimer#',1),
               (REGEXP_SUBSTR(filed_name,'#demilimer#',2)-1)
    ) col1  ,  

  substr(filed_name ,
               REGEXP_SUBSTR(filed_name,'#demilimer#',2),
               REGEXP_SUBSTR(filed_name,'#demilimer#',3)- (REGEXP_SUBSTR(filed_name,'#demilimer#',2))
    ) col2  ,
     substr(filed_name ,
               REGEXP_SUBSTR(filed_name,'#demilimer#',3),
               length(filed_name)- (REGEXP_SUBSTR(filed_name,'#demilimer#',3))
    ) col3        /* last col should take up to the length  */

from table_name
```