# rows convert in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have values like below

```
1,a,b,c
2,d,e
3,f,g
```

Expected output

```
1 a
1 b
1 c
2 d
2 e
```

Can you please help me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Splitting string into multiple rows in Oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14328621/splitting-string-into-multiple-rows-in-oracle)

Comment: Not  a pure duplicate though, since it is not just splitting the delimited values into rows, however, repeating the leading substr value in a separate column. Mostly the logic remains same, however, there needs to be an extra rule to eliminate the repeating rows as I explained in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very much close to implementing the logic to [Split comma delimited strings in a table](http://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2015/03/04/split-comma-delimited-strings-in-a-table-using-oracle-sql/). The only tricky thing is that you have the row number along with the string itself.

You could use **ROWNUM** as pseudo column, and then **filter out** those rows where the leading substr of the string is repeating with the ROWNUM.

For example,

**Setup**

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE t(text VARCHAR2(4000));

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> INSERT INTO t SELECT '1,a,b,c' text FROM dual;

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO t SELECT '2,d,e' text FROM dual;

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO t SELECT '3,f,g' text FROM dual;

1 row created.

SQL> COMMIT;

Commit complete.

SQL>
SQL> SELECT * FROM t;

TEXT
----------
1,a,b,c
2,d,e
3,f,g

SQL>
```

**Solution:**

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS(
  2  SELECT ROWNUM rn, text FROM t
  3  )
  4  SELECT *
  5  FROM
  6    (SELECT rn,
  7      trim(regexp_substr(t.text, '[^,]+', 1, lines.COLUMN_VALUE)) text
  8    FROM DATA t,
  9      TABLE (CAST (MULTISET
 10      (SELECT LEVEL FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= regexp_count(t.text, ',')+1
 11      ) AS sys.odciNumberList ) ) lines
 12    )
 13  WHERE TO_CHAR(rn) <> text
 14  ORDER BY rn
 15  /

        RN TEXT
---------- ----------
         1 a
         1 b
         1 c
         2 d
         2 e
         3 f
         3 g

7 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: Hi,lalit thank you , but it is difficult to understand, is there another option for simple Query

Comment: @Rajesh123 Well, it won't be difficult if you understand REGEXP_SUBSTR, ROW_GENERATOR method. Probably, you need to do some learning and testing. Google around for the keywords I told you.