# SQL REGEXP_SUBSTR returns null String when splitting

Tags: sql, regex, oracle11g, delimiter

I followed the instructions outlined in this post to split a delimited string into rows of a table:

[Splitting string into multiple rows in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14328621/splitting-string-into-multiple-rows-in-oracle)

The answer that worked for that particular delimited string is represented in this fiddle:

[Demo1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7db59d16c/3789/0)

```
with temp as
(
    select 108 Name, 'test' Project, 'Err1, Err2, Err3' Error  from dual
    union all
    select 109, 'test2', 'Err1' from dual
)
select distinct
  t.name, t.project,
  trim(regexp_substr(t.error, '[^,]+', 1, levels.column_value))  as error
from 
  temp t,
  table(cast(multiset(select level from dual connect by  level <= length (
        regexp_replace(t.error, '[^,]+'))  + 1) as sys.OdciNumberList)) levels
order by name;
```

Unfortunately my string is not comma delimited. It is delimited by the substring ':::'. I attempted to alter the answer to suit my situation by writing the SQL in the following fiddle:

[Demo2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7db59d16c/3805/0)

```
with temp as
(
    select 108 Name, 'test' Project, 'Err1:::Err2:::Err3' Error  from dual
    union all
    select 109, 'test2', 'Err1' from dual
)
select distinct
  t.name, t.project,
  trim(regexp_substr(t.error, '[^:::]+', 1, levels.column_value))  as error
from 
  temp t,
  table(cast(multiset(select level from dual connect by  level <= length (
        regexp_replace(t.error, '[^:::]+'))  + 1) as sys.OdciNumberList)) levels
order by name
```

As you can see I altered the test string to be delimited by ':::' and altered the regular expression to match, but the query is producing an extraneous row with a Null value for the substring returned.

Can anyone help me understand why the changes I made would be producing that extraneous row with the Null value?

Answer (score 0):

Just use `REPLACE` and your standard code with `,`

**[SqlFiddleDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7db59d16c/3818/0)**

```
 with temp as
(
    select 108 Name, 'test' Project, 'Err1:::Err2:::Err3' Error  from dual
    union all
    select 109, 'test2', 'Err1' from dual
)
select distinct
  t.name, t.project,
  trim(regexp_substr(REPLACE(t.error, ':::', ', '), '[^,]+', 1, levels.column_value))  as error
from 
  temp t,
  table(cast(multiset(select level from dual connect by  level <= length (regexp_replace(REPLACE(t.error, ':::', ', '), '[^,]+'))  + 1) as sys.OdciNumberList)) levels
order by name
```

Or you need to divide by length of delimeter:

**[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7db59d16c/3893/0)**

```
with temp as
(
    select 108 Name, 'test' Project, 'Err1:::Err2:::Err3' Error  from dual
    union all
    select 109, 'test2', 'Err1:::Err2' from dual
)
select distinct
  t.name, t.project,
  trim(regexp_substr(t.error, '[^:::]+', 1, levels.column_value))  as error
from 
  temp t,
  table(cast(multiset(select level from dual connect by  level <= length (
       regexp_replace(t.error, '[^:::]+'))/3  + 1) as sys.OdciNumberList)) levels
order by name
```

You can see why executing:

```
SELECT length (regexp_replace('Err1:::Err2:::Err3', '[^:::]+')) + 1 AS l
FROM dual
```

This will return 7 and your:

```
SELECT DISTINCT  t.name, t.project,
trim(regexp_substr(t.error, '[^:::]+', 1, levels.column_value))  as error
```

will try to get `regexp_substr` for 7 occurences where 4 of them will be `NULL` and in the end 4 `NULL` will be squashed to one `NULL` by `DISTINCT`.