# how to write oracle Query to split string into multiple lines related by category

Tags: oracle

I'm new to my job career..
I'm building an SSAS model on Visual Studio Data Tool..
one of the most complex problems I faced is a field contain multiple values that I need to connect everyone of them to another Table eg.

```
Family   PersonsID 
1         1#2#5 
2         6#7#10
```

I want a Query "not a plsql program" to make it this form

```
Family  PersonsID
1          1
1          2
1          5
2          6
2          7
2          10
```

to bound it with Persons Table.
I found this genius query

```
SELECT A.[Family],  
     Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS String  
 FROM  (SELECT [State],  
         CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE([PersonsID], '#', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS String  
     FROM  TableA) AS A CROSS APPLY String.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a);
```

it worked totally perfect as I wanted but only on SQL server. When I Tried it on Oracle 11g
It gave me error: expected "join" after Cross

can you help me.. I need it as query because I don't have permission to create functions and procedures on the DB by the client policy and I need it as fast as possible

Comment: There are several different ways to tokenize strings in Oracle.  [This thread shows several approaches](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3710589/146325).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SQL Server` and `Oracle 11g` are very different RDBMS and support different syntax(excluding ANSI standard part) so you cannot use `CROSS APPLY and XML`.

But you can use `regexp_substr` instead:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.Family,
  TRIM(regexp_substr(t.PersonsID, '[^#]+', 1, levels.column_value)) AS PersonsID
FROM TableA t,
  table(cast(multiset(select level from dual connect by  level <= length (
        regexp_replace(t.PersonsID, '[^#]+'))  + 1) as sys.OdciNumberList)) levels
ORDER BY Family, CAST(PersonsID AS INT)
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f22560/9/0)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔═════════╦═══════════╗
║ FAMILY  ║ PERSONSID ║
╠═════════╬═══════════╣
║      1  ║         1 ║
║      1  ║         2 ║
║      1  ║         5 ║
║      2  ║         6 ║
║      2  ║         7 ║
║      2  ║        10 ║
╚═════════╩═══════════╝
```

For delimeters longer than one character you can use slightly modified query presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32656639/sql-regexp-substr-returns-null-string-when-splitting/32656731#32656731).

**EDIT:**

`DISTINCT` will remove duplicates so when

```
PersonsID
1#1#2#5

=> 1 
   2
   5
```

To get all values with duplicates remove `DISTINCT`:

```
=> 1
   1
   2
   5
```

Comment: Thank you it worked perfectly great.. but I didn't understand why the "distinct" in the query?

Comment: @ray Distinct is for removing duplicates from `1#1#2#5` like http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/101b5/1/0. If you want duplicates values remove `DISTINCT`.

Answer (score 1):

Below is another way to achieve same result

```
SELECT family , trim(COLUMN_VALUE) PersonsID
FROM table1, xmltable(('"' || REPLACE(PersonsID, '#', '","') || '"'))
```