# insert to multi row in db with 1 variable input PL/SQL?

Tags: oracle

I have the input

`var1,var2,var3`

and I need to insert or update into 3 row table with split by ",", How do I do that, thank you

Comment: You should go here: [Splitting string into multiple rows in Oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14328621/splitting-string-into-multiple-rows-in-oracle). Please search before asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understood your question correctly you want to create three rows out of one input text line broken down by some delimitter. You can do this with Regex_substr

```
CREATE TABLE TEST AS ( 
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR ('var1,var2,var3','[^,]+',1 ,LEVEL) values 
FROM DUAL 
CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR ('var1,var2,var3','[^,]+' ,1 ,LEVEL) IS NOT NULL)
```

and just the insert as follow up:

```
INSERT INTO TEST (
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR ('var1,var2,var3', '[^,]+',1,LEVEL) VALUES
FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR ('var1,var2,var3','[^,]+' ,1 ,LEVEL) IS NOT NULL)
```

For the update you need to be more specific on what the operation (before -> after) shall accomplish