# How to get values between specific char that is multiply used

Tags: sql

That's my table

```
123 | 123-456-345
234 | 332-433
221 | 221
```

That's the result that I want to get

```
123 | 123
123 | 456
123 | 345
234 | 332
234 | 433
221 | 221
```

Comment: Can you please show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: what's your RDBMS?

Comment: This question has been asked before: for [MySql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17942508/sql-split-values-to-multiple-rows), [SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493510/turning-a-comma-separated-string-into-individual-rows), [Oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14328621/splitting-string-into-multiple-rows-in-oracle), ...

Comment: Don't store multiple values in a single column. Fix your data model

Answer (score 2):

With SQL-Server you could do this:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID INT,YourString VARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES(123,'123-456-345'),(234,'332-433'),(221,'221');

SELECT tbl.ID
      ,x.value('.','int') AS Value
FROM @tbl AS tbl
CROSS APPLY(SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(YourString,'-','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML)) AS Casted(AsXml)
CROSS APPLY Casted.AsXml.nodes('/x') AS A(x)
```

The trick is, to transform your string `123-456-345` to valid XML with simple replacements of `-`: `<x>123</x><x>456</x><x>345</x>`.

This XML can be queried using `.nodes()`, to get all entries one after the other

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server 2016 , use STRING_SPLIT function.

```
SELECT ID,  value  
FROM Yourtable  
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT([YourColumn], '-');
```

For lower versions of SQL server,you can either follow what @shungo suggested,or you can create a user defined function to split string and call it in the select statement.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitWords]
(    
      @Input NVARCHAR(MAX),
      @Character CHAR(1)
)
RETURNS @Output TABLE (
      Item NVARCHAR(1000)
)
AS
BEGIN
      DECLARE @StartIndex INT, @EndIndex INT

      SET @StartIndex = 1
      IF SUBSTRING(@Input, LEN(@Input) - 1, LEN(@Input)) <> @Character
      BEGIN
            SET @Input = @Input + @Character
      END

      WHILE CHARINDEX(@Character, @Input) > 0
      BEGIN
            SET @EndIndex = CHARINDEX(@Character, @Input)

            INSERT INTO @Output(Item)
            SELECT SUBSTRING(@Input, @StartIndex, @EndIndex - 1)

            SET @Input = SUBSTRING(@Input, @EndIndex + 1, LEN(@Input))
      END

      RETURN
END
```

The write the script like below.

```
SELECT ID,Item
FROM Yourtable
CROSS APPLY [SplitWords] (YourColumn,'-')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Postgres you can use `string_to_array()` and `unnest()`:

```
select t.id, x.val
from the_table t
    cross join lateral unnest(string_to_array(the_column), '-') as x(val);
```

---

But you should **really** fix your data model. Storing delimited strings in a single column is a really bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

For the Oracle 11g here is a simple solution (Just replace `tab` with *your-table-name* and `num`, `str` with *your-column-names*):

```
WITH
tab1 AS (
SELECT num, SUBSTR(str,1,3) str FROM tab
UNION ALL 
SELECT num, SUBSTR(str,5,3) str FROM tab
UNION ALL 
SELECT num, SUBSTR(str,9,3) str FROM tab
)
SELECT * 
FROM tab1
WHERE str IS NOT NULL
```

It gives me result of:

```
1   123 123
2   123 345
3   123 456
4   221 221
5   234 332
6   234 433
```