# String parsing in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have a string **425874761-G #463733361-S #48310-S**. I need an SQL to make this string into a column as below.

> ```
> Column_1        Column_2
> 425874761         G
> 463733361         S
> 48310             S
> ```

If input is **48310-S #425874761-G** then output should be

> ```
> Column_1        Column_2
> 48310              S
> 425874761          G
> ```

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could use this:

```
WITH temp AS (
    SELECT '425874761-G #463733361-S #48310-S' col1 FROM dual
)
SELECT 
    --REGEXP_SUBSTR(t.col1, '[^#]+', 1, levels.column_value) AS split_rows,
    REGEXP_SUBSTR(REGEXP_SUBSTR(t.col1, '[^#]+', 1, levels.column_value), '[^-]+', 1, 1) AS col1,
    REGEXP_SUBSTR(REGEXP_SUBSTR(t.col1, '[^#]+', 1, levels.column_value), '[^-]+', 1, 2) AS col2
FROM 
    temp t,
    TABLE(CAST(MULTISET(SELECT level FROM dual CONNECT BY level <= LENGTH (REGEXP_REPLACE(t.col1, '[^#]+'))  + 1) AS sys.OdciNumberList)) levels;
```

This answer refer solution from [string_to_rows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27137629/3844458) and [string_to_columns](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2348338)