# Oracle sql to generate combinations for each row id

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following table

**mydata:**

```
ID  NUMBERS
1   1,2
2   1,2,3,4,5
3   1,2,3
```

My ultimate goal is to generate the following **result**:

```
ID  Num
1   1
1   2
2   1
2   2
2   3
2   4
2   5
3   1
3   2
3   3
```

e.g. all the combinations for each `id` with a corresponding numbers

now... I came up with the following query

```
with mydata as (
select 1 as id, '1,2' as numbers from dual
union
select 2 as id, '1,2,3,4,5' as numbers from dual
union 
select 3 as id, '1,2,3' as numbers from dual
)
SELECT distinct  id,TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR(numbers, '[^,]+', 1, level)) lv
   FROM (
    select id, numbers
    from mydata 
  )
    CONNECT BY  level <= REGEXP_COUNT(numbers, '[^,]+')
  order by id
```

Without the `distinct` - the above query gives `66` repetitive combinations instead of `10` combinations needed (so for large data set - it will get slow..)

I wonder, is it a correct way to achieve this and is there any better and more efficient way to get the desired result.

Thanks.

Comment: That should help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14328621/splitting-string-into-multiple-rows-in-oracle . I'm marking it as duplicate.

Comment: @g00dy ok thanks. For the record - Nefreo's solution worked for me quite well.