# How can I get the required output for the given sample data in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

### My sample data

```
Table A

col1    col2
------------------------------- 
1       1,2,3
2       1,2,4,5
```

Required Output is

```
col1  col2
-------------------------
1     1
1     2
1     3
2     1
2     2
2     4   
2     5
```

How can I get the desired output in oracle? Thanks in advance

Comment: we can help you, if you have done something so far

Comment: Thank you Andam. But how can I do this in Oracle?

Comment: Have you searched in other peoples posts? If not please search first.

Comment: Thank you Kaushik Nayak.

Comment: By _"get the required output"_ it sounds like you meant _"parse comma-separated string into multiple rows"_. [Googling for that](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=oracle+parse+comma-separated+string+into+multiple+rows) gives me 224K results according to Google, with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14328621/splitting-string-into-multiple-rows-in-oracle at the top.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option:

```
SQL> with test (col1, col2) as
  2  (select 1, '1,2,3' from dual union
  3   select 2, '5,6,7,8' from dual
  4  )
  5  select col1, regexp_substr(col2, '[^,]+', 1, column_value) col2
  6  from test,
  7       table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
  8                           connect by level <= regexp_count(col2, ',') + 1)
  9                  as sys.odcinumberlist))
 10  order by col1, 2;

      COL1 COL2
---------- -------
         1 1
         1 2
         1 3
         2 5
         2 6
         2 7
         2 8

7 rows selected.

SQL>
```