# Why is this regex performing partial matches?

Tags: regex, oracle

I have the following raw data:

```
1.1.2.2.4.4.4.5.5.9.11.15.16.16.19 ...
```

I'm using this regex to remove duplicates:

```
([^.]+)(.[ ]*\1)+
```

which results in the following:

```
1.2.4.5.9.115.16.19 ...
```

The problem is how the regex handles `1.1` in the substring `.11.15.` What should be 9.11.15.16 becomes 9.115.16. How do I fix this?

The raw values are sorted in numeric order to accommodate the regex used for processing the duplicate values.

The regex is being used within Oracle's `REGEXP_REPLACE`

The decimal is a delimiter. I've tried commas and pipes but that doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: On this specific set, try `(\d+\.)(\1)+`

Comment: @revo - Ill take it! I'll accept if you write up an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately Oracle doesn't provide a token to match a word boundary position. Neither familiar `\b` token nor ancient `[[:<:]]` or `[[:>:]]`.

But on this specific set you can use:

```
(\d+\.)(\1)+
```

Note: You forgot to escape dot.

Answer (score 3):

Oracle's `REGEX` does not work the way you intended. You could split the string and find distinct rows using the general method [Splitting string into multiple rows in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14328621/splitting-string-into-multiple-rows-in-oracle). Another option is to use `XMLTABLE` , which works for numbers and also strings with proper quoting.

```
SELECT LISTAGG(n, '.') WITHIN
GROUP (
        ORDER BY n
        ) AS n
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT TO_NUMBER(column_value) AS n
    FROM XMLTABLE(replace('1.1.2.2.4.4.4.5.5.9.11.15.16.16.19', '.', ','))
    );
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/97eade/836)

Answer (score 1):

Your regex caught:

- a `1` - the **second** digit in `11`,
- then a dot,
- and finally `1` - the **first** digit in `15`.

So your regex failed to catch the whole sequence of digits.

The most natural way to write a regex catching **the whole sequence
of digits** would be to use:

- a loobehind for either the start of the string or a dot,
- then catch a sequence of digits,
- and finally a lookahead for a dot.

But as I am not sure whether Oracle supports lookarounds, I wrote
the regex another way:

```
(^|\.)(\d+)(\.(\2))+
```

Details:

- `(^|\.)` - Either start of the string or a dot (group 1), instead of
  the loobehind.
- `(\d+)` - A sequence of digits (group 2).
- `(` - Start of group 3, containing:
- `\.(\2)` - A dot and the same sequence of digits which caught group 2.
- `)+` - End of group 3, it may occur multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

**Group the repeating pattern and remove it**

As revo has indicated, a big source of your difficulties came with not escaping the period.  In addition, the resulting string having a `115` included can be explained as follows (Valdi_Bo made a similar observation earlier):

`([^.]+)(.[ ]*\1)+` will match `11.15` as follow:

```
SCOTT@DB>SELECT
  2      '11.15' val,
  3      regexp_replace('11.15','([^.]+)(\.[ ]*\1)+','\1') deduplicated
  4  FROM
  5      dual;
VAL     DEDUPLICATED
11.15   115
```

Here is a similar approach to address those problems:

**matching pattern composition**

-Look for a non-period matching list of length 0 to N (subexpression is referenced by `\1`).

'19'  which matches `([^.]*)`

-Look for the repeats which form our second matching list associated with subexression 2, referenced by `\2`.

'19.19.19' which matches `([^.]*)([.]\1)+`

-Look for either a period or end of string. This is matching list referenced by `\3`. This fixes the match of '11.15' by '115'.

`([.]|$)`

**replacement string**

I replace the match pattern with a replacement string composed of the first instance of the non-period matching list.

`\1\3`

**Solution**

```
regexp_replace(val,'([^.]*)([.]\1)+([.]|$)','\1\3')
```

Here is an example using some permutations of your examples:

```
SCOTT@db>WITH tst AS (
  2      SELECT
  3          '1.1.2.2.4.4.4.5.5.9.11.15.16.16.19' val
  4      FROM
  5          dual
  6      UNION ALL
  7      SELECT
  8          '1.1.1.1.2.2.4.4.4.4.4.5.5.9.11.11.11.15.16.16.19' val
  9      FROM
 10          dual
 11      UNION ALL
 12      SELECT
 13          '1.1.2.2.4.4.4.5.5.9.11.15.16.16.19.19.19' val
 14      FROM
 15          dual
 16  ) SELECT
 17      val,
 18      regexp_replace(val,'([^.]*)([.]\1)+([.]|$)','\1\3') deduplicate 
 19      FROM
 20      tst;
VAL                                                DEDUPLICATE             
------------------------------------------------------------------------
1.1.2.2.4.4.4.5.5.9.11.15.16.16.19                 1.2.4.5.9.11.15.16.19   
1.1.1.1.2.2.4.4.4.4.4.5.5.9.11.11.11.15.16.16.19   1.2.4.5.9.11.15.16.19   
1.1.2.2.4.4.4.5.5.9.11.15.16.16.19.19.19           1.2.4.5.9.11.15.16.19
```

My approach does not address possible spaces in the string.  One could just remove them separately (e.g. through a separate replace statement).