# Convert a piece of SQL into an Oracle function

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

My table "COMMA_SEPERATED" looks something like this

```
ID  NAME CITY
--- ---- -----------------------------
1   RAJ  CHENNAI, HYDERABAD, JABALPUR
2   SAM  BHOPAL,PUNE
```

I want to separate each City as a new record so my SQL is: (working fine)

```
SELECT id, TRIM(CITY_NEW)
FROM COMMA_SEPERATED, xmltable
(
    'if (contains($X,",")) then ora:tokenize($X,"\,") else $X'
    passing city AS X
    columns CITY_NEW varchar2(4000) path '.'
);
```

I want to convert this piece of SQL into a function so that i can simply call the function like this

```
SELECT id, split_function(city) FROM COMMA_SEPERATED
```

Output:

```
1   CHENNAI
1   HYDERABAD
1   JABALPUR
2   BHOPAL
2   PUNE
```

Can anyone help on how to do that?  I am very new to PL/SQL.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Splitting string into multiple rows in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14328621/splitting-string-into-multiple-rows-in-oracle)

Comment: That doesn't really seem to be a suitable duplicate; the question isn't about how to split a string (the OP is already using a variation on one of those solutions), it's how to encapsulate that into a function?

Comment: When you say `split_function(city)` does that mean the passed city to the function should be returned or all the rows ?

Comment: I recommend not to write this function but normalize your tables instead.

Answer (score 1):

Apart what @Alex showed, you can also create an `object` and get the `object` returned via `function`. See below:

```
--Created an object to hold your result columns
create or replace type Obj IS OBJECT (id number, city varchar2(20));
/
--Table of object
create or replace type var_obj is table of Obj;

/
--Function with return as with Object type.
create or replace function splt_fnct
return var_obj
as
var var_obj:=var_obj();

begin
Select obj(col,col1)
bulk collect into var
from (
Select  distinct  col , regexp_substr(col1,'[^,]+',1,level) col1
from tbl
connect by regexp_substr(col1,'[^,]+',1,level) is not null
order by 1);

return var;
end;

/
--Selecting result   

 select *  from table(splt_fnct);
```

Edit: I was trying with @Alex solution and got some error as shown below:

```
create or replace function splt_fnct(input_strng varchar2)
return var_obj
as
var var_obj:=var_obj();

begin
Select obj(col,col1)
bulk collect into var
from (
select tbl.col, t.rslt --<--This column name should the same as used in colmns clause in the below query. Its giving error "invalid column". How to handle this case.
FROM tbl, xmltable
(
    'if (contains($X,",")) then ora:tokenize($X,"\,") else $X'
    passing col1 AS X
    columns input_strng varchar2(4000) path '.'
) t
);
return var;
end;

/
```

Correction as per @Alex suggestion:

```
create or replace function splt_fnct(input_strng varchar2)
return var_obj
as
var var_obj:=var_obj();

begin

select obj(tbl.col, t.rslt) 
bulk collect into var
FROM tbl, xmltable
(
    'if (contains($X,",")) then ora:tokenize($X,"\,") else $X'
    passing input_strng AS X
    columns rslt  varchar2(4000) path '.'
) t;

return var;
end;

/
```

Comment: You should have `passing input_strng` and `columns rslt` ? Some of the other name references are a bit confused too I think. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=fc20d9325a0c1450a6c76568689eb7d6). But that isn't quite right still, if you're using an object you need to pass the ID in too really, otherwise when you re-query the base table inside the function you're effectively doing an unintended cross-join: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=3ad16f96994b39889f8174cdc0fbd62f).

Comment: @AlexPoole. Perfect. Thanks for your answer...!!

Answer (score 1):

The query you're trying to get to:

```
SELECT id, split_function(city) FROM COMMA_SEPERATED
```

won't work, because you're trying to return multiple rows for each source row. You have to make it a bit more complicated than that unfortunately.

If the goal is to hide the splitting mechanism then the closest I can think of is to create a function which returns a collection of strings, which could be [pipelined](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/PIPELINED-clause.html):

```
create or replace function split_function (p_string varchar2)
return sys.odcivarchar2list pipelined as
begin
  for r in (
    select result
    from xmltable (
      'if (contains($X,",")) then ora:tokenize($X,"\,") else $X'
      passing p_string as x
      columns result varchar2(4000) path '.'
    )
  )
  loop
    pipe row (trim(r.result));
  end loop;
end split_function;
/
```

Your proposed call would then give you one row per ID with a collection:

```
select id, split_function(city) from comma_seperated;

        ID SPLIT_FUNCTION(CITY)
---------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
         1 ODCIVARCHAR2LIST('CHENNAI', 'HYDERABAD', 'JABALPUR')
         2 ODCIVARCHAR2LIST('BHOPAL', 'PUNE')
```

which isn't quite what you want; but you can use a table collection expression and cross-join to convert into multiple rows instead:

```
select cs.id, t.column_value as city
from comma_seperated cs
cross join table(split_function(cs.city)) t;

        ID CITY                          
---------- ------------------------------
         1 CHENNAI                       
         1 HYDERABAD                     
         1 JABALPUR                      
         2 BHOPAL                        
         2 PUNE
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=040dd2c1abfbf0d157e7d67e2f1d53bd).

That isn't as simple as you hoped for, but is arguably still better than cross-joining to the `xmltable()`, particularly if you want to reuse that splitting logic/function in multiple places, as well as hide the details of how the split is done - which would let you change the mechanism easily if you wanted to, e.g. to use a more common regular expression to do the splitting.

Comment: Alex am not sure if `passing p_string` will actually work in this case. If we have to use this, the statement should be dynamically. I tried and it was failing in my case.

Comment: @XING - not quite sure why it would need to be dynamic; it worked when tested (in 11gR2), and I've added a db<>fiddle demo of the same code. Curious what yours is failing on? And `p_string` is just the function parameter name, which is passed the comma-separated string from the base table as part of the call - so it's flexible and not tied to a particular table.

Comment: Might be i would be doing something wrong. I would share my code to understand the fault.. Thanks for your response.

Comment: Can you please look at my question posted above ?