# Using count(*) to fetch more than one row in a SQL Procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I'm trying to return the number of rows per invoice_id using a function and procedure. Some invoice_id's have more than one row and I'm not sure how to fetch the count when I execute my procedure. As an example invoice_id(7) has just one row, but invoice_id(100) has four rows of information.

```
Create or replace function return_num_rows_function(invoice_id_text in varchar2)
    Return varchar2
    Is inv_id varchar2(20);
    Begin
    Select count(*)invoice_id into inv_id from invoice_line_items where invoice_id=invoice_id_text;
    Return inv_id;
    End;



 Create or replace procedure return_num_rows (invoice_id_text in varchar2)
    Is inv_id varchar(20);
    line_item_desc invoice_line_items.line_item_description%type;
    Begin
    inv_id := return_num_rows_function(invoice_id_text);
    If inv_id is not null then
    Select count(*)invoice_id, line_item_description into inv_id,line_item_desc
    From invoice_line_items where invoice_id = inv_id;
    dbms_output.put_line('The number of rows returned:'|| inv_id);
    dbms_output.put_line('Item description(s):'|| line_item_desc);
    End if;
    End;

    set serveroutput on;
    execute return_num_rows(7);
```

Comment: If you want to return the number of records then the retrun type of the function should be a `Number`. Why you made it a `varchar`? Also if  your function query is returning more then 1 rows then you need a table function which return all the rows. You can also use a `sys_refcursor` to get your result.

Comment: Table function?

Comment: Read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52850468/convert-a-piece-of-sql-into-an-oracle-function/52851223#52851223

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert a piece of SQL into an Oracle function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52850468/convert-a-piece-of-sql-into-an-oracle-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First of all do not use a string type variable for a numeric one
  (`invoice_id_text`).
- For your case it's better to use a procedure instead of called
  function ( `return_num_rows_function` ), since you need two out
  arguments returned.
- A SQL Select statement cannot be used without `Group By` with aggegated and non-aggregated columns together ( *i.e. don't use this one :*

  ```
    Select count(*) invoice_id, line_item_description 
      into inv_id,line_item_desc
      From invoice_line_items 
     Where invoice_id = inv_id;
  ```

  )

*So, Try to create below procedures :*

```
    SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE Procedure 
    return_num_rows_proc(
                         i_invoice_id        invoice_line_items.invoice_id%type,
                         inv_id          out pls_integer,
                         line_item_desc  out invoice_line_items.line_item_description%type
                        ) Is
    Begin
    for c in
     (
      Select line_item_description
        into line_item_desc
        From invoice_line_items
       Where invoice_id = i_invoice_id
     )
     loop
       line_item_desc := line_item_desc||'  '||c.line_item_description;
       inv_id := nvl(inv_id,0) + 1;
     end loop;
    End;
    /

    SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE Procedure 
       return_num_rows(
                      i_invoice_id pls_integer
                      ) Is

      inv_id         pls_integer;
      line_item_desc invoice_line_items.line_item_description%type;
    Begin
       return_num_rows_proc(i_invoice_id,inv_id,line_item_desc);
      If inv_id is not null then
        dbms_output.put_line('The number of rows returned:' || inv_id);
        dbms_output.put_line('Item description(s):' || line_item_desc);
      End if;
    End;
    /
```

*and call as in your case :*

```
SQL> set serveroutput on;
SQL> execute return_num_rows(7);
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace inv_id varchar2(20) with inv_id number;
and also if you want to get two outputs from procedure better to use refcursor.