# Oracle SQL - Select distinct values from a given list

Tags: sql, oracle, distinct

I have searched extensively to try find a way of selecting distinct values from a given list that don't exist in a table, but there doesn't seem to be a simple way of doing this.

I was wondering if this is possible to do somehow, or is the easiest solution to put the values into a table and select distinct from there?

This is the gist of what I am trying to do:

`Select distinct column_name from dual 
where column_name in ('one','two','two','elephant');`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The alternative for "**dual joins**" is the built in varchar2 array.
Here is the example

```
select distinct column_value
from   table(
         sys.odcivarchar2list(
           'one','two','two','elephant'
         )
       )
```

Answer (score 0):

The constructs with `in` won't work, unless you have a query that returns all values you specify and maybe a bit more, so if you have a set of letters, you could input it in a query that returns all letters. That would give you something like this:

```
select
  *
from (
  select chr(96 + level) as letter
  from dual
  connect by level <= 26)
where
  letter in ('a', 'a', 'b');
```

Of course, that would work for fixed limited sets, like the whole alphabet, or even numbers from 1 to 1000, but it's not a way to convert any set to a distinct list.

**Alternative: dual joins**

You can select a single value using the fake table `dual`. You can even make a union of such selects, although it looks a bit cumbersome:

```
select 'a' as MyValue from dual
union select 'a' from dual
union select 'b' from dual
```

If you use `union` instead of `union all`, the query will implicitly return distinct values only.

**Alternative: Split string**

If you have the values in a string, you could split that string and return the items. There are various ways to do that, but not out of the box. You could have a look at the question [Splitting string into multiple rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14328621/splitting-string-into-multiple-rows-in-oracle) to which the answers show various solutions.

Comment: Thank you for you answer, but I've edited the question to better reflect what I am trying to do. The dataset will be large and made up of many varchar words rather than individual letters, I think the methods you have shown above might be more effort than it would be worth but thank you for showing that method!

Comment: Jup, i'd look at the  alternative  solutions  or the other question then.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
select distinct trim(regexp_substr('a,b,b,c','[^,]+', 1, level) ) value
from dual
connect by regexp_substr('a,b,b,c', '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null
```