# Comparing 2 sets of data in the same table - oracle

Tags: oracle, dataset, comparison, union

Lets say i have a table with the following data.

```
+-------------------------------+
|   UniqueID  Name    Dataset   |
+-------------------------------+
| 1         ABC1    A:B;C:D;E:F |
| 2         ABC2    A:B;C:D;R:S |
| 3         ABC3    C:4;G:5;A:B |
| 4         ABC4    A:B;C:D;E:F |
+-------------------------------+
```

where dataset is combinations of data e.g. A:B, delimited by ;

Effectively what i want to do do is compare each set of data against the other record and build a picture up like the following by comparing 'Dataset' to get result like this (this is just the first comparison)

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| UniqueID  Name    UniqueID   Name    Matched on  OnlyinBase OnlyinTarget |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 1         ABC1    2          ABC2    A:B;C:D       E:F           R:S     |
| etc                                                                      |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

What is the best way to do the above?

Comment: I fixed the sample data delimiters - sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *think* your sample data set isn't correct.

- Shouldn't for `ID = 2` `D` be separated from `R` by semi-colon (not comma)?
- Shouldn't for `ID = 3` `5` be separated from `A` by semi-colon (not colon)?

I *fixed* that (if it should be fixed) and wrote the following PL/SQL code; I don't know whether you can do that in pure SQL. Have a look, see if it helps.

What does it do? Using nested loops, splits all `DATASET`s into rows and - using `SET` operators (`INTERSECT`, `MINUS`) decides which group the result belongs to (matched / only in base / only in target).

```
SQL> select * from test;

        ID NAME DATASET
---------- ---- --------------------
         1 ABC1 A:B;C:D;E:F
         2 ABC2 A:B;C:D;R:S
         3 ABC3 C:4;G:5;A:B
         4 ABC4 A:B;C:D;E:F

SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL>
SQL> DECLARE
  2     l_matched   VARCHAR2 (20);
  3     l_base      VARCHAR2 (20);
  4     l_target    VARCHAR2 (20);
  5  BEGIN
  6     FOR cur_1 IN (  SELECT id, name, dataset
  7                       FROM test
  8                   ORDER BY id)
  9     LOOP
 10        FOR cur_2 IN (  SELECT id, name, dataset
 11                          FROM test
 12                         WHERE id > cur_1.id
 13                      ORDER BY id)
 14        LOOP
 15           -- Matched
 16           SELECT LISTAGG (col, ';') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY col)
 17             INTO l_matched
 18             FROM (    SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR (cur_1.dataset,
 19                                             '[^;]+',
 20                                             1,
 21                                             LEVEL)
 22                                 col
 23                         FROM DUAL
 24                   CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT (cur_1.dataset, ';') + 1
 25                   INTERSECT
 26                       SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR (cur_2.dataset,
 27                                             '[^;]+',
 28                                             1,
 29                                             LEVEL)
 30                                 col
 31                         FROM DUAL
 32                   CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT (cur_2.dataset, ';') + 1);
 33
 34           -- Only in base
 35           SELECT LISTAGG (col, ';') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY col)
 36             INTO l_base
 37             FROM (    SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR (cur_1.dataset,
 38                                             '[^;]+',
 39                                             1,
 40                                             LEVEL)
 41                                 col
 42                         FROM DUAL
 43                   CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT (cur_1.dataset, ';') + 1
 44                   MINUS
 45                       SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR (cur_2.dataset,
 46                                             '[^;]+',
 47                                             1,
 48                                             LEVEL)
 49                                 col
 50                         FROM DUAL
 51                   CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT (cur_2.dataset, ';') + 1);
 52
 53           -- Only in target
 54           SELECT LISTAGG (col, ';') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY col)
 55             INTO l_target
 56             FROM (    SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR (cur_2.dataset,
 57                                             '[^;]+',
 58                                             1,
 59                                             LEVEL)
 60                                 col
 61                         FROM DUAL
 62                   CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT (cur_2.dataset, ';') + 1
 63                   MINUS
 64                       SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR (cur_1.dataset,
 65                                             '[^;]+',
 66                                             1,
 67                                             LEVEL)
 68                                 col
 69                         FROM DUAL
 70                   CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT (cur_1.dataset, ';') + 1);
 71
 72           DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (
 73                 cur_1.id
 74              || ' '
 75              || cur_1.name
 76              || ' '
 77              || cur_2.id
 78              || ' '
 79              || cur_2.name
 80              || ' '
 81              || rpad(l_matched, 20, ' ')
 82              || ' '
 83              || rpad(l_base, 20, ' ')
 84              || ' '
 85              || rpad(l_target, 20, ' '));
 86        END LOOP;
 87     END LOOP;
 88  END;
 89  /
1 ABC1 2 ABC2 A:B;C:D              E:F                  R:S
1 ABC1 3 ABC3 A:B                  C:D;E:F              C:4;G:5
1 ABC1 4 ABC4 A:B;C:D;E:F
2 ABC2 3 ABC3 A:B                  C:D;R:S              C:4;G:5
2 ABC2 4 ABC4 A:B;C:D              R:S                  E:F
3 ABC3 4 ABC4 A:B                  C:4;G:5              C:D;E:F

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: I fixed the sample data delimiters thanks for pointing out - reading through your answer now!

Comment: This worked perfectly. I was wondering if there is a faster way to implement the regex as it doesn't seem to scale well...

Comment: Well, for such an approach (sets, I mean), you have to split that string to rows. I guess that any other approach might be even slower. If possible, modify your data model so that it is normalized (as current one isn't - you shouldn't store different info in the same column).

Comment: So i should create a procedure to split the data first...and then try the above....sorry i am no expert with pl/sql and i'm not a developer either..

Comment: Huh, right ... it would be easier if you were a developer :) When I said that "data model" isn't right, it means that you should create some more tables, drop (or recreate) current ones. I guess you won't be doing that. For one time only, yes - you might write some code to split data and store the result into some other table, but - if you're going to use such a code more than once, that won't be a good solution either. Unfortunately, you're paying for someone else's mistakes.

Comment: Thanks! I will open another question as i have the data in a more normalised format...but struggling to implement the above with that new structure

Comment: cheeky link to the new question...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54476625/joining-2-data-sets-in-oracle-via-intersection-in-oracle-pl-sql

Answer (score 1):

Alternative solution in one query:

```
with 
  -- sample data
  t(Id, Name, Dataset) as (
    select 1, 'ABC1', 'A:B;C:D;E:F' from dual union all
    select 2, 'ABC2', 'A:B;C:D;R:S' from dual union all
    select 3, 'ABC3', 'C:4;G:5;A:B' from dual union all
    select 4, 'ABC4', 'A:B;C:D;E:F' from dual ),
  -- end of sample data
  q as (
    select distinct id, name,
           trim(regexp_substr(t.dataset, '[^;]+', 1, ls.column_value)) as ds
      from t, table(cast(multiset(select level from dual 
                                  connect by level <= length(regexp_replace(t.dataset, '[^;]+'))+1) 
                         as sys.odcinumberlist)) ls),
  p as (select q1.id id1, q1.name name1, q2.id id2, q2.name name2, q1.ds set1, q2.ds set2, 
               max(case when q1.ds = q2.ds then 1 else 0 end) 
                   over (partition by q1.id, q2.id, q1.ds) m1, 
               max(case when q1.ds = q2.ds then 1 else 0 end) 
                   over (partition by q1.id, q2.id, q2.ds) m2
          from q q1 join q q2 on q1.id <> q2.id),
  a1 as (select distinct id1, id2, set1 ds from p where m1 = 0),
  a2 as (select distinct id1, id2, set1 ds from p where m1 = 1),
  a3 as (select distinct id1, id2, set2 ds from p where m2 = 0)
select t1.id id1, t1.name name1, t2.id id2, t2.name name2, 
       (select listagg(ds, ' ; ') within group (order by ds) 
          from a1 where id1 = t1.id and id2 = t2.id) l1, 
       (select listagg(ds, ' ; ') within group (order by ds) 
          from a2 where id1 = t1.id and id2 = t2.id) l2, 
       (select listagg(ds, ' ; ') within group (order by ds) 
          from a3 where id1 = t1.id and id2 = t2.id) l3
  from t t1
  join t t2  on t1.id <> t2.id;
```

Result:

```
   ID1 NAME1    ID2 NAME2 L1            L2                L3
------ ----- ------ ----- ------------  ----------------  -------------
     1 ABC1       2 ABC2  E:F           A:B ; C:D         R:S
     1 ABC1       3 ABC3  C:D ; E:F     A:B               C:4 ; G:5
     1 ABC1       4 ABC4                A:B ; C:D ; E:F
     2 ABC2       1 ABC1  R:S           A:B ; C:D         E:F
     2 ABC2       3 ABC3  C:D ; R:S     A:B               C:4 ; G:5
     2 ABC2       4 ABC4  R:S           A:B ; C:D         E:F
     3 ABC3       1 ABC1  C:4 ; G:5     A:B               C:D ; E:F
     3 ABC3       2 ABC2  C:4 ; G:5     A:B               C:D ; R:S
     3 ABC3       4 ABC4  C:4 ; G:5     A:B               C:D ; E:F
     4 ABC4       1 ABC1                A:B ; C:D ; E:F
     4 ABC4       2 ABC2  E:F           A:B ; C:D         R:S
     4 ABC4       3 ABC3  C:D ; E:F     A:B               C:4 ; G:5
12 rows selected
```

Subbquery `q` uses one of the splitting techniques from SO to [divide words into separate rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14328621/splitting-string-into-multiple-rows-in-oracle). Then I self-joined data and counted matching / non-matching words. Subqueries `a1` - `a3` are needed only because function `listagg` does not respect `distinct` clause.

This solution compares (1 and 4) and (4 and 1). You can change this to show results only once by replacing `<>` in `t1.id <> t2.id` and `q1.id <> q2.id` with `<`.