# Getting text from multiple brackets

Tags: sql, oracle, regexp-substr

For Oracle SQL

i have the below tag format: `{ABCDE,12345}{47,CE}`

```
SELECT 
    [column a] 
    [column b] 
    [column c] 
FROM 
    [table name] 
WHERE 
    [*content of column d*] IN {ABCDE,12345} 
    [*content of column e*] IN {47,CE}
```

So i need my query to look at what's in the tag and select all rows that have the same contents if:
- column D = the first set of brackets
- column E = the content in the second set

Comment: Also, there are plenty of existing questions on tokenizing strings [such as this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14328621/146325). You need to explain what makes your problem different enough to require another one.

Comment: @APC i actually realize how badly i explained my needs, so i'll start again.

{ABCDE,12345}{47,CE} is a tag. my query looks like this:
SELECT
[column a]
[column b]
[column c]
FROM
[table name]
WHERE
[content of column d] IN {ABCDE,12345}
[content of column e] IN {47,CE}

I need a dinamic formula though, since the data between brackets {} is subject to change, therefore i need the query to match it depending on the contents between brackets. Hope this makes any sense.

Comment: Can you show some actual data?  How do you "have" the tag data?  Is it coming from a column?

Answer (score 0):

One option might be this (see comments within code):

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select '{ABCDE,12345}{47,CE}' from dual),
  3  temp as
  4    -- remove leading and trailing brackets
  5    -- replace "middle" brackets with semi-colon (a new separator)
  6    (select replace(substr(col, 2, length(col) - 2), '}{', ';') val
  7     from test
  8    )
  9  select regexp_substr(val, '[^;]+', 1, level) result
 10  from temp
 11  connect by level <= regexp_count(val, ';') + 1;

RESULT
--------------------------------------------------------------------
ABCDE,12345
47,CE

SQL>
```

---

Ah, yes - separate **columns**: then, `substr` might help:

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select '{ABCDE,12345}{47,CE}' from dual)
  3  select substr(col, 2, instr(col, '}{') - 2) val1,
  4         substr(substr(col, instr(col, '}{') + 2),
  5                1,
  6                length(substr(col, instr(col, '}{') + 2)) - 1
  7               ) val2
  8  from test;

VAL1        VAL2
----------- -----
ABCDE,12345 47,CE

SQL>
```