# How to use SQL query to make second line after character "|"?

Tags: sql, oracle

May I know how to use SQL select query to make new line after character ("|") ?

[image: URL SQL]

Comment: I'd guess a recursive cte (WITH) can be used.

Comment: I think you want something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14328621/splitting-string-into-multiple-rows-in-oracle

Answer (score 0):

You can use `REPLACE` as follows:

```
replace(your_str,'|',chr(10))
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=074971b282131dd1ec41f95deb62f993)

Comment: Hi, i tried use replace but not successful due to after "|" is next record, i thinking use join could be can solve this, but i no idea how to use join query ?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean new line in SQL you can try it

```
DECLARE @NewLineChar AS CHAR(2) = CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)

PRINT ('SELECT FirstLine AS MyFirstLine ' + @NewLineChar + 'SELECT SecondLine AS MySecondLine')
```

Comment: sorry, make you confusing, new line is next record.

Comment: That's invalid for Oracle

Answer (score 0):

you can also this table-value function. you can set your entire text into function as well as a delimiter that is "|" in your case, finally it return multiple records based on how many "|" was exist.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[Split] ( @string NVARCHAR(MAX), @delimiter CHAR(1)) RETURNS @output TABLE(splitdata NVARCHAR(MAX)) 

BEGIN 
    DECLARE @start INT, @end INT 
    SELECT @start = 1, @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string) 
    WHILE @start < LEN(@string) + 1 BEGIN 
        IF @end = 0  
            SET @end = LEN(@string) + 1
       
        INSERT INTO @output (splitdata)  
        VALUES(SUBSTRING(@string, @start, @end - @start)) 
        SET @start = @end + 1 
        SET @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string, @start)
        
    END 
    RETURN 
END
```

If your problem wont solve feel free to ask again.

RaminHbb