# CONNECT BY in Snowflake query

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a SQL query that runs fine in Oracle. It uses LEVEL and CONNECT BY in query. How I can convert this query so that I can run it in Snowflake db.

```
Select level, regexp_substr('AAAA,BBBB,CCCC','[^,]+',1,level) as COL1 from dual
connect by regexp_substr('AAAA,BBBB,CCCC','[^,]+',1,level) is not null;
```

Comment: Snowflake also supports the CONNECT BY syntax with support for LEVEL. https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/connect-by.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This particular query seems to be an attempt to implement string split(Related: [Splitting string into multiple rows in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14328621/splitting-string-into-multiple-rows-in-oracle)):

```
Select level, regexp_substr('AAAA,BBBB,CCCC','[^,]+',1,level) as COL1 
from dual 
connect by regexp_substr('AAAA,BBBB,CCCC','[^,]+',1,level) is not null;

/*
    LEVEL   COL1
1   AAAA
2   BBBB
3   CCCC
*/
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6785ae722e1249db6b9307ca2a9ab039)**

---

Snowflake supports natively [recursive queries](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/queries-hierarchical.html)(both in a form of CONNECT BY and recursive CTE).

But it is much easier to achieve it using built-in  **[SPLIT_TO_TABLE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/split_to_table.html)**:

```
SELECT t.index, t.value
FROM TABLE(SPLIT_TO_TABLE('AAAA,BBBB,CCCC', ',')) AS t;
```

Sidenote: Literal translations are not always the best approach.

A general rule for migrating any kind of code between different systems: behaviour first(WHY/WHAT) and then implementation(HOW).