# SQL | SPLIT COLUMNS INTO ROWS

Tags: oracle, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

How can I split the column data into rows with basic SQL.

```
COL1 COL2
1     A-B
2     C-D
3     AAA-BB
```

Result

```
COL1 Col2
1     A
1     B
2     C
2     D
3     AAA
3     BB
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle? (The answer will not suit both...)

Comment: Will it always be the first and third character? (Or can it be ABC-DD?)

Comment: ORACLE SQL, IT CAN BE ABC-DD

Comment: Or is it simply delineated by a `-` to denote splits and you could have A-B-C-D and need 4 rows?

Comment: If ABC-DD or A-B-C-D are possible, add those to the sample data and also adjust the expected result.

Comment: @xQbert Yes: Its '-' is the delimeter

Comment: Looks like this has been asked and has several offered solutions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14328621/splitting-string-into-multiple-rows-in-oracle  will need to substitute - for , in answers though.  I've always taken the recursive CTE approach but nice to see other possibilities.

Comment: This is a rather incomplete question and needs more context. Which version of SQL are you using? MS SQL? MySql or Oracle? @Neel please edit the question and tags to suite more what youre asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Oracle 12, if it is always two delimited values then you can use:

```sql
SELECT t.col1,
       l.col2
FROM   table_name t
       CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
         SELECT SUBSTR(col2, 1, INSTR(col2, '-') - 1) AS col2 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT SUBSTR(col2, INSTR(col2, '-') + 1) FROM DUAL
       ) l
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (COL1, COL2) AS
SELECT 1, 'A-B' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'C-D' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'AAA-BB' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | COL1 | COL2 |
> | --- | --- |
> | 1 | A |
> | 1 | B |
> | 2 | C |
> | 2 | D |
> | 3 | AAA |
> | 3 | BB |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6815fe13c618cc25e5cd61f40ac06f8a)*

Answer (score 1):

`Snowflake` is tagged, so here's the snowflake way of doing this:

```
WITH TEST (col1, col2) as
      (select 1, 'A-B' from dual union all
       select 2, 'C-D' from dual union all
       select 3, 'AAA-BB' from dual
      )
SELECT test.col1, table1.value 
FROM test, LATERAL strtok_split_to_table(test.col2, '-') as table1
ORDER BY test.col1, table1.value;
```

Answer (score 0):

For MS-SQL 2016 and higher you can use:

```
SELECT Col1, x.value
FROM t CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(t.Col2, '-') as x;
```

BTW: If Col2 contains null, it does not appear in the result.

Answer (score 0):

As of Oracle:

```
SQL> with test (col1, col2) as
  2    (select 1, 'A-B' from dual union all
  3     select 2, 'C-D' from dual union all
  4     select 3, 'AAA-BB' from dual
  5    )
  6  select col1,
  7    regexp_substr(col2, '[^-]+', 1, column_value) col2
  8  from test cross join
  9    table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
 10                        connect by level <= regexp_count(col2, '-') + 1
 11                       ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
 12  order by col1, col2;

      COL1 COL2
---------- ------------------------
         1 A
         1 B
         2 C
         2 D
         3 AAA
         3 BB

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```