# how to extract all words from a string column in sql oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to extract all words of a column into a new column in SQL Oracle.
For example I have the sample data

```
select 'extract words' as title from dual
union 
select 'words in a phrase' from dual
```

That gives me this table

| Title |
| --- |
| words in a phrase |
| extract words |

I want as result:

| Words |
| --- |
| words |
| in |
| a |
| phrase |
| extract |
| words |

Comment: What ave you tried so far?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Splitting string into multiple rows in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14328621/splitting-string-into-multiple-rows-in-oracle)

Answer (score 1):

Here's one method

```
SELECT title, seq,RTRIM(SUBSTR(title,INSTR(' '||title,' ',1,seq),INSTR(' '||title||' ',' ',1,seq+1) - INSTR(' '||title,' ',1,seq)))
  FROM (select 'extract words' as title from dual
         union 
         select 'words in a phrase' from dual),
       (SELECT ROWNUM seq FROM dual  CONNECT BY LEVEL < 100) x
 WHERE INSTR(' '||title,' ',1,seq) > 0       
 ORDER BY 1,2
```

Answer (score 1):

Very basically:

```sql
select csv_id, regexp_substr (
         csv_text,
         '[^,]+',
         1,
         rn
       ) val
from   csvs
cross  join lateral (
  select level rn from dual
  connect by level <=   
    length ( csv_text ) - length ( replace ( csv_text, ',' ) ) + 1
);
```

[Here](https://blogs.oracle.com/sql/post/split-comma-separated-values-into-rows-in-oracle-database) is exhaustive guide on how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another take.  You could always select 'level' as well, say after the 'id' and see the word's position in the title if you wished.

This uses the with clause to just set up the test data.  Then for each row, "loop" through each word using connect by where the word's characters are followed by a space or the end of the line.  It loops the number of occurrences of a space in the line plus one for the last word.

```
with tbl(id, title) as (
  select 1, 'extract words' as title from dual union all 
  select 2, 'words in a phrase' from dual
)
select id, regexp_substr(title, '(.*?)( |$)', 1, level, NULL, 1) as words
from tbl
connect by level <= regexp_count(title, ' ') + 1
  and prior id = id
  and prior sys_guid() is not null;


        ID WORDS            
---------- -----------------
         1 extract          
         1 words            
         2 words            
         2 in               
         2 a                
         2 phrase           

6 rows selected.
```